# Как обновить окно в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня есть Request.xaml файл где есть мно-во и TextBox-ы Combox-ов и кнопка, так вот мне нужно при нажатии ее чтобы текст в TextBox-ах вернулся в дэфолтное состояние. Мне нужно это реализовать, чтобы пользователь мог опять ввести данные туда, а я при этом при нажатии кнопки еще и сохранил эти данные.

Еще повторю вопрос как или обновить окно, или во все Combox-ах вернуть дефолтное значения.

```
page.DataContext = null;
page.DataContext = new Foo();
```

Но я не понял, что это. Несколько подробнее вопрос описан тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068788/how-to-reload-reset-the-whole-page-in-wpf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, вы путаете визуальное состояние с логическим. Визуальное состояние «обновлять» не надо: WPF рисует всё правильно за вас, UI всегда в правильном состоянии без вашего участия.

Что вы хотите, так это вернуть начальные значения полей.

Если вы пишете на WPF как на WinForms, без MVVM/`DataContext`, и реализуете логику в code behind — вы ССЗБ, ничего иного, чем просто ручное присвоение полям фиксированных значений в code behind по нажатию кнопки вы сделать не можете.

Если же вы модный чувак и ваши данные приходят к вам через `Binding`/`DataContext`, то совет переподключить этот самый `DataContext` как раз правильный и должен сработать.

Comment: А как можно "переподключить" `DataContext`? Я обычно задаю контекст в xaml.

Comment: @Aarnihauta: Просто присвоить :) `DataContext` — доступное для записи свойство.

Comment: @Aarnihauta: Я бы избегал задавать `DataContext` прямо в XAML, не вьюшное это дело — создавать себе `DataContext`. Вот немного по теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/10105.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [UIElement.InvalidateVisual()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatevisual.aspx)