# Точка входа в MVVM: App.xaml.cs или представление?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Начал изучать MVVM и столкнулся, как наверное и многие другие, с определенным недопониманием. В многочисленных примерах реализации MVVM, доступных в сети, авторы разными способами подходят к **точке входа** в приложение *(могу ошибаться в определении)*. Некоторые меняют аттрибут *StartupUri*, другие просто его полностью удаляют и в перегруженном методе *OnStartup* файла *App.xaml.cs* вручную создают экземпляр окна и устанавливают ему свойство *DataContext*. Нашел в сети несколько примеров по MVVM и mvvm-light ([пример 1](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Design-Patterns-MVVM-Model-d4b512f0), [пример 1](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Design-Patterns-MVVM-Model-f1d7c05c), [пример 3](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Design-Patterns-MVVM-Model-d60c7e4b), [пример 4](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Design-Patterns-MVVM-23dee872) и [пример 5](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Design-Patterns-MVVM-9f7fccaf)) и в них автор вообще не изменяет *App.xaml* или *App.xaml.cs* и только в одном изменяет code-behind (так и не понял как это называется по-русски) представлений.

Мне ясно, что как и любой паттерн MVVM является рекомендацией и не запрещает отходить от правил в разумных пределах, но какая разница между этими подходами? Какие выгоды и подводные камни? Какой подход позволяет в дальнейшем более гибко расширять и сопровождать приложение (плагины, расширения и т.д.)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Я предпочитаю не использовать `StartupUri`, а переопределять `OnStartup`, и создавать главное окно там ([[1]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/520245/10105), [[2]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/508362/10105), [[3]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/525998/10105)).

Причина в том, что указание `StartupUri` не позволяет задать `DataContext` снаружи окна. А хардкодирование `DataContext`'а внутри XAML неправильно, так как:

- Согласно паттерну MVVM, View не должно руководить VM, и знать о нём должно как можно меньше. То есть код, обслуживающий UI, не должен создавать себе VM сам.
- Чаще всего VM должна получить ещё какие-то аргументы в конструкторе (например, модельные объекты), а это не получится сделать, если VM создаётся в XAML'е (откуда XAML может знать о модели?).
- Иногда перед открытием главного окна нужна дополнительная логика, требующая показа своего маленького окна (например, предложение обновить программу). Или нужно выяснить, какое именно из окон нужно показывать в начале. Код, выясняющий это и при некоторых условиях показывающий дополнительное окно, проще разместить в `OnStartup`.
- Главная VM может понадобиться вам для ещё чего-нибудь. Поэтому если её создаёт класс `App`, он может сохранить ссылку на неё у себя, чтобы другие (например, побочное окно) могли быть привязаны к тому же экземпляру VM. Иначе вам придётся лезть за главной VM в экземпляр главного окна.

В любом случае, MVVM не догма, делайте так, как вам удобнее.

Comment: Ваши разъяснения как всегда исчерпывающие. Пытаюсь найти какой-либо проект, в котором были-бы реализованы все часто возникающие вопросы при изучении MVVM. Видя код и пути вызовов в дебагере наглядней было бы понять. Имеется ввиду комуникация между компонентами, использование команд, событие-в-команду (event-to-command). В идеале, конечно увидеть как правильно реализуется система плагинов. Может быть Вы знаете, где можно такой проект найти?

Comment: @XelaNimed: Нет, я не знаю. Мне приходилось доходить до всего на собственном опыте и в обсуждениях с другими участниками сайта.