# Принцип, структура и использование WPF фреймворка mvvmlight

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Пытаюсь разобраться с [MVVM Light](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/). И чем дальше, тем страшнее. Вопросы возникают как снежный ком. В сети не нашел ни одной статьи, где бы простым русским языком объяснялся бы mvvm-light и его практическое применение. Ниже я приведу места и моменты, которые вызывают у меня непонимание.

Установил на VisualStudio 2015 MVVM Light, создал новый проект MvvmLight(WPF451). В проекте создались следующие файлы и папки:

```
[Design]
    DesignDataService.cs
[Model]
    DataItem.cs
    DataService.cs
    IDataService.cs
[Skins]
    MainSkin.xaml
[ViewModel]
    MainViewModel.cs
    ViewModelLocator.cs
App.xaml
App.xaml.cs
MainWindow.xaml
MainWindow.xaml.cs
```

В файле `App.xaml` видим следующее `<Application ... StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" ...>`. Как было выяснено [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562578), это не подходит по ряду причин, а поэтому нужно удалить этот атрибут и в перегруженном методе `OnStartup` класса `App` создать экземпляр необходимой модели представления и установить её как `DataContext`, примерно так:

```cs
public partial class App : Application {

    MainViewModel mainVM = new MainViewModel();

    static App() {
        DispatcherHelper.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        new MainWindow() { DataContext = mainVM }.Show();
    }
}
```

, но при использовании в созданном проекте mvvm-light класс `MainViewModel` принимает в конструкторе `IDataService dataService`. В проекте так и не нашел каким образом создается этот `dataService`. Для каждой ли модели представления нужно этот `dataService` создавать? Как, когда и где он используется?

---

Также в созданном проекте присутствует класс `ViewModelLocator`. В комментарии класса указан пример использования:

```cs
/*
In App.xaml:
<Application.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModelLocatorTemplate xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MvvmProject.ViewModel"
                               x:Key="Locator" />
</Application.Resources>

In the View:
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=ViewModelName}"
*/
```

, но вроде же как явное указание `DataContext` в XAML неправильно?! Или я не прав?! Для чего и как он используется?

В code-behind представления `MainWindow` к событию `Closing` добавляется очистка `ViewModelLocator`:

```
Closing += (s, e) => ViewModelLocator.Cleanup();
```

, но в `ViewModelLocator` ничего не добавляется. Или это происходит где-то далеко за кулисами?!

---

В файле `MainWindow.xaml` существует привязка к ресурсу:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Как я понял, это используется только для работы с визуальным редактором и в рабочей версии никакой роли не играет. Поправьте меня, если я не прав.

---

В сети присутствует множество примеров mvvm-light, но они все сводятся к слепому следованию инструкциям, без пояснения для чего это делается и как это в последствии используется. Предвидя упреки об изучении мат.части, отмечу, что мне лично материал легче усваивается на практике. И не хотелось бы колотить себе шишки, а перенять опыт знающих людей и сразу учить *как* нужно делать, а не как *можно*. Может существует какой-либо проект в сети, который подробно описывает использование mvvm-light фреймворка **на русском**?

Comment: Так возьмите другой фреймворк для обучения.

Comment: @vitidev например?! По какому фреймворку есть документация на русском?!

Comment: Необязательно использовать MVMM Light, все необходимые инструменты можно создать самостоятельно, или дернуть из того же MVVM Light

Comment: @S.Kost я с Вами согласен, но как писал выше хотелось бы как *нужно*, а не как *можно*. Моя квалификация не позволит самостоятельно создать хороший велосипед. А если дергать из MVVM Light, то возвращаемся к моему вопросу: "Как его использовать?"

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое - следовать рекомендации, и делать все через `ViewModelLocator`. `DataService` создается через инъекции из IoС контейнера.

Так регистрация происходит в `ViewModelLocator.cs`
в конструкторе пишем

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataTask, DebugDataContext>();
```

где `DebugDataContext` - конкретная реализация интерфейса `IDataTask` например база данных для дебага, а в продакшене будет с другого места браться (но это уже совсем другая история).

Регистрируем VM

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
```

Выставляем ее на публику

```
public MainViewModel             Main           => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
```

Все это есть уже по умолчанию, для других форм просто по аналогии.
И вот когда вьюха будет обращаться к VM посредством того кода в XAML автоматически через `IoC` будет цепляться нужный источник данных. Вам там ответили, что вьюха не должна создавать VM. но она и не создает, создает IoC-контейнер, вьюха только запрашивает его экземпляр. Так что вам там не совсем верно ответили, без инъекций все действительно так, но в MVVM Light уже есть IoC и вся парадигма строится вокруг инъекций

В коде можно тоже, если очень хочется, но лично я не вижу в этом смысла

`mainVM = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();`

Конечно всё это ИМХО, у VlaD'a свои взгляды, у меня свои, и MVVM это не святое писание, а просто идея и используют ее по разному, но по задумке создателей MVVM Light это должно делаться примерно так как я описал.