# отслеживание изменения свойств не отходя от шаблона MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding

у меня на view есть TreeView и ListBox как мне в зависимости от того что выбрано в TreeView изменить данные в ListBox? 
Нашел у TreeView эвент SelectedItemChanged но не понимаю как его использовать с привязыванием. По факту мне просто нужен вызов функции в котором я напишу нечто вроде

```
RegValues = SelectedKey.GetContent();
```

кусочек view.xaml

```
<TreeView Name="tree" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewData}" 
                SelectedValuePath="{Binding SelectedKey}"
              >

        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildGroup}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

кусочек viewmodel.cs

```
public List<String> RegValues
    {
        get {
            int i = 0;
            return (List<String>)GetValue(RegValuesProperty); 
        }
        set { SetValue(RegValuesProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RegValuesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("RegValues", typeof(List<String>), typeof(Level2PageViewModel));

public RegModel SelectedKey
    {
        get { return (RegModel)GetValue(SelectedKeyProperty); }
        set
        {SetValue(SelectedKeyProperty, value);}
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedValue.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedKeyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedKey", typeof(RegModel), typeof(Level2PageViewModel));

public List<RegModel> TreeViewData
        {
            get { return (List<RegModel>)GetValue(TreeViewDataProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TreeViewDataProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TreeViewData.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TreeViewDataProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TreeViewData", typeof(List<RegModel>), typeof(Level2PageViewModel));
```

Comment: для привязки следует использовать не события, а свойства - в вашем случае создайте еще одно свойство во вьюмодел и привяжете его к `SelectedItem` у `TreeView`

Comment: Да, и кто вас учил использовать во вьюмодел `DependencyProperty`? Это дичь, если честно. Используйте обычные свойства с реализацией `INotifyPropertyChanged`. DependencyProperty` годны лишь для кодбихайнд, но не для вьюмодел.

Comment: @Bulson спасибо. меня никто не учил, увидел использование DependencyProperty во вьюмодели в каком то видео на ютубе. если у вас есть какой нибудь хороший источник на тему того где и что использовать буду очень признателен.

Comment: Расскажите лучше, что именно вы хотите показывать. Расскажите о вашей задаче на более высоком уровне. Так будет понятнее, как вашу задачу правильно решать.

Comment: @VladD Мне необходимо выводить реестр windows соответственно окно выглядит примерно так же как regedit слева treeview справа датагрид. Есть класс который содержит в себе ключреестра, его подкаталоги и его наполнение реализованное другим классом.

следовательно по клику на строчку treeview я хочу чтобы изменялся контент в датагриде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле всё просто.

Заводите свойство типа `ObservableCollection<RegistryValue>`, пускай называется `Values`. В начале оно содержит пустую коллекцию.

У вас в VM есть свойство `SelectedKey`. Вы на его изменении должны сделать новое заполнение `Values`, значениями из текущего ключа. К `Values` вы привязываете вашу правую панель, `DataGrid` или просто `ListView`.

Теперь, как подписаться на изменение `SelectedKey`? Это легче сделать, если ваши свойства определены через `INotifyPropertyChanged`, там вы можете просто вызвать нужную функцию из сеттера.

```
private RegModel selectedKey
public RegModel SelectedKey
{
    get { return selectedKey; }
    set { if (Set(ref selectedKey, value)) UpdateValues(); }
}
```

(функцию `Set` можно посмотреть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/616413/10105)).

Если вы таки хотите пользоваться DependencyProperty в VM (там им по идее не место, им место во View), пишите так:

```
public RegModel SelectedKey
{
    get { return (RegModel)GetValue(SelectedKeyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedKeyProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedKeyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SelectedKey", typeof(RegModel), typeof(Level2PageViewModel),
         new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((o, args) =>
                 {
                     var self = (Level2PageViewModel)o;
                     self.UpdateValues();
                 }));
```

Вроде бы всё.

---

P. S.: Ваше свойство `RegValues` — это наверное то, что я имел в виду под `Values`.

Comment: спасибо. но почему место DependencyProperty во вью? я думал что в коде вью ничего не должно быть в принципе Оо

Comment: @Dark32167: Ну, смотрите, вот у вас есть контрол, например, `StackPanel`. Он же тоже во View, правильно? И у него есть куча `DependencyProperty`. Если вы создаёте свой контрол, то вам нужны какие-то свойства, вы не можете создать новый тип контрола вовсе без code-behind. Вот их имеет смысл оформлять как `DependencyProperty`.