# Как правильно строить клиент(WPF)-серверное(???) приложение

Tags: c#, .net

Здравствуйте, я еще невероятно "зеленый" как в программировании так и построении архитектуры. Вот пытаюсь изучить как правильно писать клиент-серверное приложение. Точнее до этого момента писал обычный клиент с субд которая находилась на локальном компьютере. Хотелось бы, чтобы клиент обращался к серверу СУБД на другом компе\ноуте(у меня для проб и ошибок в распоряжении стационар и ноут). Как я себе представляю архитектуру моего разрабатываемого клиент-серверного приложения: у меня есть клиент который обращается к некоторому серверу(может TCP\IP или HTTP серверу или же это может быть некий WCF сервис, тут тоже не разбираюсь), а сервер в свою очередь генерирует запрос к субд которая находиться у меня на другом компе, после чего с субд поступает результат запроса на сервер на котором идет генерация файла расширения json или же xml или обратно на клиенте я их распарсиваю и достаю данные. Является правильным такой подход?
 В общем хотел бы узнать вашего мнения, наставления по этому поводу, мб кто-то может посоветовать отличные гайды\литературу? Раньше ни разу не писал\не настраивал некий сервер, что хотелось бы уже уметь. П.C.: Приложение WPF

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/616413/10105

Comment: Не много не понял, причем тут MVVM паттерн, он грубо говоря для проектирования самого клиента, меня больше интересует в архитектурном паттерне "клиент-сервер" серверная сторона. Клиент я думаю смогу написать, а вот склепать сервер, соединить его с клиентом и моим ноутом на котором субд..

Comment: Если вам нужен просто коннект к БД, то промежуточный сервер писать нет смысла. Если сервер должен ещё какой то логикой обладать - то есть смысл сделать WPF-сервер-СУБД

Comment: Ну, например, если мне, дополнительно, необходимо обрабатывать поступающие запросы организовывая безопасность, шифруя, дешифруя данные, или же проверяя права\разрешения на подобные дествия, вести логи, подобного рода задачи. Наверное я бы делал это на стороне сервера. Я погуглю еще дополнительно, скорей всего как промежуточный сервер для соединения буду писать WCF сервис

Comment: @SergeyIvanyuk: Пример, который я привёл — это пример клиента, сервер там заменён на имитацию (и взаимодействие с ним тоже).

Comment: Ну в общем я дальше буду идти в направлении: Клиент WPF + MVVM паттерн, сервис WCF к которому будет обращаться клиент, а сам сервес проделывая некоторые действия будет обращаться к СУБД на другом компе, после чего сервис получит данные, сгенерирует в нужном формате и отправит клиенту.