# Изменение представления DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml

Доброго времени суток, Всем! Недавно стал изучать WPF, для меня это все ново, так что не обессудьте.

Вообщем, появилась нужна выводить отображать список изделий в DataGrid. Дело в том, что контент, который должен быть в каждой ячейки DataGrid'а должен состоять из изображения изделия и его имени. Следовательно поменял шаблон у DataGridCell:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="ComposeStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

После всех этих действий у меня получается такая картинка:
[image: скриншот]
Тоесть получается, что DataGrid понимает контент построчно, что в данном случае меня не устраивает. Мне нужно сделать так, что естественно не было у DataGrid'а никакого Header'а столбцов, и чтобы один объект из DataGrid.ItemsSource привязывался ни к целой строке, а к ячейке.

Как такое можно реализовать, не подскажите?

Comment: Вам не нужен `DataGrid`, используйте, например, `ListBox`, в качестве `ItemsPanel` установите ему `WrapPanel` или `UniformGrid`

Comment: спасибо, действительно, теперь все как положено. Хотел бы сразу же спросить еще такой момент, можно ли менять в UniformGrid стили самих ячеек? Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы каждая ячейка в UniformGrid являлась кнопкой, которая состоит уже из Border, StackPanel, Image и TextBox. Я могу конечно задать специальный стиль для кнопки, и помещать его в шаблон ListBoxItem

Comment: Посмотрите этот ответ, часть по разметку как раз то что вам нужно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/615927/wpf-%d0%a2%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-xaml/616413#616413

Comment: Спасибо, много чего прояснилось:)