# ItemsControl и виртуализаия всего списка

Tags: c#, wpf

Так как почти все готово, но есть проблемы даже при тестах с `ItemsControl`.
Существует следующий, почти кастомный контрол (будет сделан перенос после окончания):

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListPreviewInfo}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel ItemWidth="180" Orientation="Horizontal"
                           IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Background="White"
                        BorderBrush="LightSlateGray"
                        CornerRadius="3"
                        Margin="2.5"
                        BorderThickness="1">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Source="{Binding PeviewImage}" />
                        <Border ToolTip="{Binding PreviewTitle}" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="AnimTitle" Background="WhiteSmoke" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Padding="2.5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="3,3,0,0">
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                                       Margin="2.5"
                                       TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="{Binding PreviewTitle}" />
                        </Border>
                        <Border Grid.Row="2" Background="WhiteSmoke" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Padding="2.5"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="0,0,3,3"
                                Height="{Binding ElementName=AnimTitle, Path=ActualHeight}">
                            <TextBlock ToolTip="{Binding PreviewAltName}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                                       Margin="2.5"
                                       TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="{Binding PreviewAltName}" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        <ItemsControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsSource" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                   FontSize="16" Foreground="LightSeaGreen"
                                                   Text="{x:Static langs:lang.ApplicationLoadAnimeList}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.Style>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

В него, должно поместиться **2610** и более элементов.

Суть проблемы:

> При полной загрузке всех данных, мало того что отъедается 2.5 ГБ ОЗУ так еще и все элементы которые прогрузились, но не видны остаются в памяти.

Как данную проблему можно решить? Возможна идея с переписыванием класса `WrapPanel`.

Comment: а есть возможность не грузить в него сразу все элементы?

Comment: @AlexandrAlexandr, была идея сделать пагинацию, с разделами на страницы, но пока не решил, но возможность есть.

Comment: А если вместо `WrapPanel` использовать `VirtualizingStackPanel`?

Comment: @Андрей, а у него есть поведение схожее с `WrapPanel`?

Comment: Возможно, вам сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/616413/10105

Answer (score 3):

Разделите систему по принципу модель-отображение-контроллер (Почитайте про принципы MVC). Подгружайте только отображаемые объекты. Думаю это весьма логично, с учетом вашего кол-ва данных. держать в оперативке 2.5 Гб - не норма

Comment: А почему MVC, а не более подходящий для WPF MVVM?