# Создание экземпляра model во viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Можно ли создавать экземпляр model внутри viewmodel ? 
Допустим в целях использования методов модели во viewmodel. 
Не нарушает ли это паттерн mvvm ? 
И , если можно, пример, пожалуйста, как это правильно реализовать

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/379255/10105

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно. В простейшем случае именно так и нужно делать. V "запрашивает" у VM некий интерфейс, а VM с помощью средств, предоставляемых M реализует этот интерфейс. Под интерфейсом я здесь принимаю набор свойств и команд, которые V хочет предоставить конечному пользователю. В более сложных случаях, если у вас есть несколько моделей, VM может получать экземпляр M в качестве параметра конструктора, например.

Answer (score 2):

Можно. И создавать, и использовать. Согласно MVVM, VM имеет право знать о M и управлять ей.

По поводу примера — загляните, например, [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615927/10105).