# Как на WPF правильно сверстать такой календарь? Сложный компонент с кастомным дизайном

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Допустим у  меня есть классы:

```
public class YearOfLife
{
    public int YearAbsolute;
    public int YearRelative;

    public List<Week> Weeks = new List<Week>();
}

public class Week
{
    public string Tooltip;

    public WeekType WeekType;

    public DateTime Start;
    public DateTime End;
}

public enum WeekType
{
    Empty,
    Passed,
    Future,
    PossibleFuture
}
```

И допустим у меня есть код который генерирует данные:

```
List<YearOfLife> Life = new List<YearOfLife>()

public void ReGenerateLife()
{
    Life.Clear();

    var yearStart = new DateTime(DayBirth.Year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    yearStart = yearStart.AddDays(8 - (int)yearStart.DayOfWeek);

    for (var i = yearStart; i <= DayDeath2; i = i.AddYears(1))
    {
        var tmpYear = new YearOfLife();
        tmpYear.YearAbsolute = i.Year;
        tmpYear.YearRelative = i.Year - DayBirth.Year;

        Life.Add(tmpYear);
    }

    var currDate = yearStart;

    while (currDate <= DayDeath2)
    {
        var lstItem = Life.Where(a => a.YearAbsolute == currDate.Year).ToList()[0];

        var week = new Week();
        week.Start = currDate;
        week.End = currDate.AddDays(6);

        if (currDate < DayBirth)
        {
            week.WeekType = WeekType.Empty;
        }
        else if (currDate <= DateTime.Today)
        {
            week.WeekType = WeekType.Passed;
        }
        else if (currDate <= DayDeath)
        {
            week.WeekType = WeekType.Future;
        }
        else if (currDate <= DayDeath2)
        {
            week.WeekType = WeekType.PossibleFuture;
        }

        lstItem.Weeks.Add(week);
        currDate = currDate.AddDays(7);
    }
}
```

Заполнение работает на отлично (хотя и требует некоторых доработок):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть еще заготовка на XAML где решена часть задачи:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ColumnDefinition" x:Key="lifecol" >
        <Setter Property="SharedSizeGroup" Value="A"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="RowDefinition" x:Key="liferow" >
        <Setter Property="SharedSizeGroup" Value="A"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox Grid.Row="2" Name="lifeControlWrapper" Background="AliceBlue" ItemsSource="{Binding Life}">   
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding YearsAbsolute}" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding YearsRelative}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <Grid  Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition  Style="{StaticResource lifecol}"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Style="{StaticResource liferow}"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Button Name="brnFirst"  Width="auto" Margin="2" Grid.Column="0" Height="{Binding ElementName=brnFirst, Path=Width}"></Button>
                        <Button Width="auto" Margin="2" Grid.Column="1"></Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Результат должен получится приблизительно следующий:
[image]

[Более детальный пример результата](http://img.hurtom.com/i/2019/01/img_2.png)

При этом я хотел бы получить возможность скейла вместе с окном, а клетки что бы оставались при этом квадратными (реализовал частично)

Вопросы:

1. Как сделать на основе тех данных которые генерируются в `Life` вывод кнопок на каждую "неделю" ? Не писать же кнопку на каждую неделю в году?(строке) что бы потом выводить ее биндингом вручную?
2. Как сделать отступы на каждых 5ти клетках? (вертикально и горизонтально)
3. Как сделать изменение цвета кнопки в зависимости от WeekType?
4. Как сделать автоизменение шрифта количества лет в зависимости от размера окна в неких рамках?

....

Короче, как добиться того результата, который на картинке, **если учесть что я хочу это все сделать ПРАВИЛЬНО с точки зрения работы с WPFом,** а не просто сделать.

Нужен код + объяснение почему было сделано так/почему такой подход правильный. Без фанатичного разжевывания. А только на основных идеях.

Comment: **Назначу награду в 200 балов репутации как только станет возможным. Если ответ будет дан до этого времени, то награда сразу же будет присвоена ему.**

Comment: Вопрос достаточно общий и большой, я постараюсь расписать как бы сделал я, но по времени не знаю на сколько это растянется, т.к. работой присыпало. Скорее всего, буду писать по частям.

Comment: чай не календарь для подсчета остатка до выхода на пенсию пишете?)

Comment: @Gardes смешно) Вообще-то все намного депресивнее и прозаичнее.Графическое отображение жизни начиная от рождения и до смерти в неделях. Это после подсчета остатка жизни до смерти :D Негативная мотивашка, короче. Но про пенсию тоже забавная идея, этот функционал тоже можно добавить :D

Comment: @Andrew, посмотрите обновление, есть ли по нему какие-то вопросы? Если нет, то правильно ли я понял, что осталось реализовать п. 3?

Comment: просмотрю через пару часов, начну задавать доп.вопросы если будут и просмотрю что не учтено. Спасибо!

Comment: @АндрейNOP А могу ли я где-то достать репозиторий? А то у меня проблемы, даже, на стадии копирования из даного ответа в тестовый проэкт --__--" ... Капец как все сложно. Мне явно нужно будет больше времени что бы разобратся как все это работает. Я ожидал что будет сложно, но не ожидал что на столько. =(

Comment: Завтра выложу репо. На самом деле ничего тут сильно сложного нету, скорее всего вы просто не привыкли к разметке, она громоздкая, поэтому я всячески с ней борюсь в виде этой кучи Extensions.   Привязки, свойства зависимости, конвертеры, ItemsControl, шаблоны – это всё самые азы wpf, без них он просто не имеет смысла и знать их надо обязательно, ну и самописная панель это чуть-чуть более продвинутый уровень, но тоже всё просто – написать 2 метода.

Comment: Добавил ссылку на репо

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо, сажусь смотреть. Я переношу все в чат и туда напишу уже весь список глупых вопросов, которые явно скоро у меня появятся :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88655/discussion-between-andrew-and--nop).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В вашем макете основополагающим размером является размер ячейки календаря, габариты заголовков зависят от него. Поскольку я не смог придумать изящного способа пробросить результат измерения размера ячейки из панели лежащей в шаблоне `ItemsControl` наружу, то мы поступим наоборот — вычислим размер ячейки снаружи и будем его передавать и в панель самого календаря и в панели его заголовков. Бонусом — можно использовать одну и ту же панель как для календаря, так и для его заголовков.

Итак, бросим в корневой Grid окна безобидный `ContentControl` и с помощью конвертера запишем в его `Tag` размеры ячейки.

У меня есть такая заготовка для конвертеров:

```
abstract class MultiConverterBase : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
{
    public abstract object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture);
    public virtual object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;
}
```

Она реализует `MarkupExtension`, поэтому её чуть удобнее использовать в разметке — не нужно создавать дополнительный ресурс. Итак, конвертер:

```
class SplitGridCellLengthConverter : MultiConverterBase
{
    public override object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var totalLength = (double)values[0];
        var cells = (int)values[1];
        var shortSpace = (double)values[2];
        var longSpace = (double)values[3];
        var longSpacePeriod = (int)values[4];
        var totalNum = Math.Max(cells - 1, 0);
        var longNum = totalNum / longSpacePeriod;
        var shortNum = totalNum - longNum;
        var totalSpace = longNum * longSpace + shortNum * shortSpace;
        return Math.Max(totalLength - totalSpace, 0) / cells;
    }
}
```

Нам потребуются некоторые константы, вроде количества столбцов в календаре и прочего, возможно они у вас будут лежать в VM, я же использую еще пачку расширений разметки:

```
class ValueExtension<T> : MarkupExtension
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public ValueExtension() { }
    public ValueExtension(T value) => Value = value;
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => Value;
}

class IntExtension : ValueExtension<int>
{
    public IntExtension() { }
    public IntExtension(int value) : base(value) { }
}

class DoubleExtension : ValueExtension<double>
{
    public DoubleExtension() { }
    public DoubleExtension(double value) : base(value) { }
}
```

Теперь пишем:

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ContentControl Name="CellLengthHelper" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <ContentControl.Tag>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{c:SplitGridCellLengthConverter}">
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                <Binding Source="{c:Int 53}"/>
                <Binding Source="{c:Double 2}"/>
                <Binding Source="{c:Double 5}"/>
                <Binding Source="{c:Int 5}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </ContentControl.Tag>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

Теперь, когда у нас есть размер ячейки, мы можем его использовать как высоту и ширину ячеек календаря (квадратные же), а также как высоту заголовков строк и ширину заголовков столбцов

Теперь пишем панель, которая будет размещать свои элементы в ячейках одинакового размера с большими и малыми отступами:

```
public class SplitGrid : Panel
{
    #region AP
    public static int GetColumn(DependencyObject obj)
        => (int)obj.GetValue(ColumnProperty);

    public static void SetColumn(DependencyObject obj, int value)
        => obj.SetValue(ColumnProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Column", typeof(int),
            typeof(SplitGrid), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public static int GetRow(DependencyObject obj)
        => (int)obj.GetValue(RowProperty);

    public static void SetRow(DependencyObject obj, int value)
        => obj.SetValue(RowProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RowProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Row", typeof(int),
            typeof(SplitGrid), new PropertyMetadata(0));
    #endregion AP

    #region DP
    public int Columns
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(ColumnsProperty);
        set => SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Columns), typeof(int), typeof(SplitGrid),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure), ValidateColumns);

    private static bool ValidateColumns(object value) => (int)value > 0;

    public int Rows
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(RowsProperty);
        set => SetValue(RowsProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RowsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Rows), typeof(int), typeof(SplitGrid),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure), ValidateRows);

    private static bool ValidateRows(object value) => (int)value > 0;

    public double ShortSpace
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(ShortSpaceProperty);
        set => SetValue(ShortSpaceProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShortSpaceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ShortSpace), typeof(double), typeof(SplitGrid),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));

    public double LongSpace
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(LongSpaceProperty);
        set => SetValue(LongSpaceProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LongSpaceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(LongSpace), typeof(double), typeof(SplitGrid),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));

    public int LongSpacePeriod
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(LongSpacePeriodProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LongSpacePeriodProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LongSpacePeriodProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(LongSpacePeriod), typeof(int), typeof(SplitGrid),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(5, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure), ValidateLongSpacePeriod);

    private static bool ValidateLongSpacePeriod(object value) => (int)value > 0;

    public double CellWidth
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(CellWidthProperty);
        set => SetValue(CellWidthProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CellWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(CellWidth), typeof(double), typeof(SplitGrid),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(double.PositiveInfinity, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));

    public double CellHeight
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(CellHeightProperty);
        set => SetValue(CellHeightProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CellHeightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(CellHeight), typeof(double), typeof(SplitGrid),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(double.PositiveInfinity, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));
    #endregion DP

    // Этап подсчета занимаемого места
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        columns = Columns;
        rows = Rows;
        shortSpace = ShortSpace;
        longSpace = LongSpace;
        longSpacePeriod = LongSpacePeriod;
        cellWidth = CellWidth;
        cellHeight = CellHeight;
        var cellSize = new Size(cellWidth, cellHeight);

        // Обязанность панели запросить желаемое место элементов
        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
            child.Measure(cellSize);

        // Если размеры ячейки не заданы, выбираем размер наибольшего элемента
        if (double.IsInfinity(cellWidth))
            cellWidth = InternalChildren.Cast<UIElement>().Max(child => child.DesiredSize.Width);
        if (double.IsInfinity(cellHeight))
            cellHeight = InternalChildren.Cast<UIElement>().Max(child => child.DesiredSize.Height);

        // Итоговые желаемые размеры панели
        double width = CalcTotalSpace(columns - 1) + columns * cellWidth;
        double height = CalcTotalSpace(rows - 1) + rows * cellHeight;
        return new Size(width, height);
    }

    // Этап размещения элементов
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            int column = GetColumn(child);
            int row = GetRow(child);
            double x = column * cellWidth + CalcTotalSpace(column);
            double y = row * cellHeight + CalcTotalSpace(row);
            var childBounds = new Rect(x, y, cellWidth, cellHeight);
            // Размещаем
            child.Arrange(childBounds);
        }

        double width = CalcTotalSpace(columns - 1) + columns * cellWidth;
        double height = CalcTotalSpace(rows - 1) + rows * cellHeight;
        return new Size(width, height);
    }

    private int columns;
    private int rows;
    private double shortSpace;
    private double longSpace;
    private int longSpacePeriod;
    private double cellWidth;
    private double cellHeight;

    private double CalcTotalSpace(int totalNum)
    {
        if (totalNum < 0) return 0;
        int longNum = totalNum / longSpacePeriod;
        int shortNum = totalNum - longNum;
        return longNum * longSpace + shortNum * shortSpace;
    }
}
```

Тестируем. VM:

```
class MainVm : Vm
{
    public List<WeekVm> Weeks { get; } = new List<WeekVm>();

    public MainVm()
    {
        // Считаем что неделя относится к тому году,
        //  к которому относится понедельник
        var date = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);
        while (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
            date = date.AddDays(1);
        var endDate = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1);
        int weekNum = 0;
        while (date < endDate)
        {
            int year = date.Year;
            var week = new WeekVm(year - 2000, weekNum);
            Weeks.Add(week);
            date = date.AddDays(7);
            if (date.Year > year) weekNum = 0;
            else weekNum++;
        }
    }
}

class WeekVm : Vm
{
    public int YearNum { get; }
    public int WeekNum { get; }

    public WeekVm(int yearNum, int weekNum)
    {
        YearNum = yearNum;
        WeekNum = weekNum;
    }
}
```

В корневой грид добавляем:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Weeks}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <c:SplitGrid Columns="53" Rows="10" ShortSpace="2" LongSpace="5" LongSpacePeriod="5"
                             CellWidth="{Binding Tag, ElementName=CellLengthHelper}"
                             CellHeight="{Binding Tag, ElementName=CellLengthHelper}"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="c:SplitGrid.Column" Value="{Binding WeekNum}"/>
                <Setter Property="c:SplitGrid.Row" Value="{Binding YearNum}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Запускаем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь заголовки. Я воспользовался идеей [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/616413/218063) и написал такой класс для представления заголовка на стороне View:

```
class HeaderItem
{
    public int Index { get; }
    public string Text { get; }
    public HeaderItem(int index, string text)
    {
        Index = index;
        Text = text;
    }
}
```

И такой конвертер, который будет генерировать нам список `HeaderItem`:

```
class HeaderListConverter : MultiConverterBase
{
    public override object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var start = (int)values[0];
        var count = (int)values[1];
        var delta = (int)values[2];
        var headerList = Enumerable
                            .Range(start, count)
                            .Where(h => h % 5 == 0)
                            .Select(h => new HeaderItem(h - delta, $"{h}"));
        return headerList;
    }
}
```

Используем внутри корневого `Grid`:

```
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{c:HeaderListConverter}">
                <Binding Source="{c:Int 1}"/>
                <Binding Source="{c:Int 53}"/>
                <Binding Source="{c:Int 1}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <c:SplitGrid Columns="53" ShortSpace="2" LongSpace="5" LongSpacePeriod="5"
                             CellWidth="{Binding Tag, ElementName=CellLengthHelper}"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="c:SplitGrid.Column" Value="{Binding Index}"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-20,0,0,0"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="{Binding Tag, ElementName=CellLengthHelper}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{c:HeaderListConverter}">
                <Binding Source="{c:Int 0}"/>
                <Binding Source="{c:Int 10}"/>
                <Binding Source="{c:Int 0}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <c:SplitGrid Rows="10" ShortSpace="2" LongSpace="5" LongSpacePeriod="5"
                             CellHeight="{Binding Tag, ElementName=CellLengthHelper}"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="c:SplitGrid.Row" Value="{Binding Index}"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-10,2,-10"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="{Binding Tag, ElementName=CellLengthHelper}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я привязал размер шрифта заголовка к размеру ячейки, это не самое гибкое решение, но вы можете написать конвертер, который будет использовать некий коэффициент масштаба, а также принимать максимальное и минимальное значение размера шрифта.

Тут вы уже можете заметить, что изменение размеров окна начинает притормаживать (если в настройках Windows включена опция "Отображать содержимое окна при перетаскивании), т. к. на каждый пиксель (даже чаще) пройденный мышью происходит пересчет размеров ячейки, потом отрисовка заголовков, при этом место под календарь тоже меняется, меняется размер ячейки и т. д. пока не будут рассчитаны окончательные размеры.

Я написал немного кода для перехвата сообщений и выставления простой текстовой заглушки вместо контента окна:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
        HwndSource source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
        source.AddHook(WndProc);
    }

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        switch (msg)
        {
            case 0x0231: // WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE
                content = Content;
                Content = new TextBlock
                {
                    Text = "Обновление...",
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
                };
                break;
            case 0x0232: // WM_EXITSIZEMOVE
                Content = content;
                break;
        }
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    private object content;
}
```

Вы можете вместо этого выставить в окне DP и поставить на него триггер в разметке и выводить какую-то более привлекательную заглушку.

<sub>продолжение следует...</sub>

Репозиторий с проектом на GitHub: [WpfSplitGrid](https://github.com/AndrewNowosad/WpfSplitGrid)

Comment: только вот количество клеток  там не обязательно 53. Может быть 1-54. Это так, на всякий случай. Вот более точный пример: https://img.hurtom.com/i/2019/01/img_2.png . Спасибо за выделение времени =^_^=

Comment: Ага, ну тогда надо будет переписать панель так, чтобы положение ячейки устанавливалось не по порядку, а с явным указанием строки и столбца с помощью AP. В принципе не сложно, но это уже не сегодня :) Тогда VM недели должна будет хранить в себе номер года и свой номер внутри этого года

Comment: @Andrew, панель переписал, продолжение будет позже. Не понял как у вас может быть 54 недели, неделя может относиться сразу к двум годам что ли? Имхо, она должна быть ровно 7 дней и относиться только к одному году, иначе подсчет неделями будет неверный

Comment: Если на вашей картинке посчитать, например, 2011+2012+2013 годы, то получится 53+54+53=160 недель, хотя фактически их там никак не больше (365+366+365)/7=157

Comment: Ну, например, если просчитывать количество недель через Calendar: `calendar.GetWeekOfYear()` оно может выдать 54 недели(хотя в основном 53) :) Так что это не я придумал. А вот если считать тем способом который написан в моем коде в моем здешнем вопросе -- то выходит меньше недель. 52 чаще всего и иногда 53. И учитывая оба эти факты я назвал число 54. Чисто что бы перебдеть.

Comment: Эээ, с какими параметрами, например?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/m8qp8y

Comment: Второй параметр равен наверное `CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay`? Он принимает даже один день за целую неделю, мне кажется это неправильным, впрочем к сути топика это не относится