# Постраничный вывод информации из бд

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

Как мне реализовать вывод картинок(по 4 штуки в строке) из базы данных в ListBox и переключение между страницами с помощью кнопок(< - влево и > - вправо)? Получаю данные из бд вот таким образом:

```
UsersEntities bs = new UsersEntities();
            var data = from p in bs.Pictures
                       select p;
            List<Pictures> pictureslist = new List<Pictures>();
            foreach(var el in data)
            {
                pictureslist.Add(new Pictures { pictId = el.Id, pict = el.Img });
            }
            lb1.DataContext = pictureslist;
            lb1.ItemsSource = pictureslist;
```

Класс Pictures:

```
class Pictures
        {
            public int pictId { get; set; }
            public byte[] pict { get; set; }
        }
```

XAML код ListBox'a:

```
<ListBox Name="lb1" ItemsSource="{Binding Pictureslist}">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid IsItemsHost="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding pict}" Width="40" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

C вышепоказанным кодом фотографии выводятся по 5 штук, а мне нужно по 4.

Comment: А в базе сколько у вас картинок? Вопрос слишком общий, вы не знаете как получать ровно по 4 картинки из бд? При чем тут тогда wpf?

Comment: Если вопрос именно по wpf, то вот отличный дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615927/218063

Comment: Уважаемый, а есть ли вообще смысл вам отвечать? 90%, что вы не ответите на заданный вопрос, либо не отметите ответ верным. С таким подходом вы вряд ли что либо тут найдете полезного. Будьте более активней!

Comment: @АндрейNOP в бд 18 фотографий. И я не понимаю как сверстать такой интерфейс с помощью которого я смогу выводить в бд фотографии по 4 штуки.