# обратиться к элементу элемента

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**Как обратиться к элементу Label?**

```
<Button x:Name="but" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="256,126,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="237" Height="183">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Label x:Name="txt" Height="100" Width="100"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: А какую задачу вы решаете? В стилях обычно переделывают вид самого элемента, но не засовывают туда другой для того, что бы потом обращаться к нему.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ну тогда я не правильно это сделал, я только начинаю с wpf знакомиться. Если так, возможно ли и правильно ли один элемент засовывать в другой?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я вспомнил... суть такова, я делал внешний вид и добавлял элементы, но если добавлять элементы вне этой конструкции то будет виден только внешний вид, а эти элементы будут невидимы.

Comment: Не добавляйте элементы вручную, используйте ItemsControl и шаблоны

Comment: @АндрейNOP можете пример написать, чтоб понятно было как это делать

Comment: Так я не знаю что вы делаете вообще. Посмотрите вот этот пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615927/218063