# Не меняется значение контента с помощью триггера

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Имеется код пагинатора, который должен при контенте с значением `0` сделать кнопку неактивной, а так же установить контент кнопки как `...`:

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Paginator.Pages}" Padding="3.5">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                            ClipToBounds="False" IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ItemsControl">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                                    <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.Style>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=DataContext.LoadPage}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        MinWidth="15" MinHeight="10" Margin="2.5"
                        Padding="4,2.5,4,2.5" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger
                                    Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}"
                                    Value="0">
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="…" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

```
public class PaginatorViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public static readonly PropertyData PaginatorProperty = RegisterProperty(nameof(Paginator), typeof(IPaginatorModel));

    public static readonly PropertyData LoadPageProperty = RegisterProperty(nameof(LoadPage), typeof(TaskCommand<int>));

    public override string Title => "Paginator";

    public PaginatorViewModel(IPaginatorModel paginatorModel, IMessageService messageService, TaskCommand<int> commandLoadPage)
    {
        Paginator = paginatorModel;
        LoadPage = commandLoadPage;
    }

    public TaskCommand<int> LoadPage
    {
        get => GetValue<TaskCommand<int>>(LoadPageProperty);
        set => SetValue(LoadPageProperty, value);
    }


    public IPaginatorModel Paginator
    {
        get => GetValue<IPaginatorModel>(PaginatorProperty);
        private set => SetValue(PaginatorProperty, value);
    }

    protected override async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        await base.InitializeAsync();
    }

    protected override async Task CloseAsync()
    {
        await base.CloseAsync();
    }
}
```

Но смены контента не происходит.

[image: Пагинатор]

Почему так происходит, и как добиться нормального результата?

Comment: Потому что значение, присвоенное явно имеет самый высокий приоритет. Что бы значение мог изменить триггер, оно должно устанавливаться в стиле

Comment: Т.е. уберите `Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"` и добавьте в стиль перед триггером `<Setter Property="Content" Value="{TemplateBinding Content}" />`. (Почему там, кстати, `TemplateBinding`?)

Comment: Ну а вообще, хороший пример как сделать пагинацию в WPF здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/616413/218063

Comment: Не выходит, если убрать `TemplateBinding` тогда контента не будет, а через стили его не установить, причину не могу выяснить. `член "Content" не является допустимым, так как не имеет соответствующего имени типа.`

Comment: Вот здесь порядок применения значения для DP: [Dependency Property Setting Precedence List](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence#dependency-property-setting-precedence-list)

Comment: Как-то всё слишком сложно у вас. Какой-то фреймворк используете?

Comment: Да, фреймворк `Catel`.

Comment: Изучите пример по ссылке, я рекомендую использовать подход оттуда, сильно облегчите себе жизнь