# WPF ListBox постраничный скролл с использованием MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

Есть ListBox в котором может быть несколько сотен элементов. Обычный скролл в данном случае не очень удобен, поэтому хочется сделать возможность листать содержимое страницами. Соответственно под ListBox'ом добавить панель навигации:
< Назад 1 2 ... 15 Вперед >
Гугл по вопросу постраничного скролла ListBox'а подсказывает использовать VerticalOffset и ViweportHeight. Но это подразумевает много кода в codebehind.
Подскажите, можно ли реализовать такое, используя MVVM? И если можно, то как?

Comment: Это смотрели: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/616413/218063 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я много где поискал, но не нашел вменяемого примера для **MVVM** кроме [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/616413/218063) и решил все-таки написать еще один, и сделать его как можно проще. На помощь приходит `ICollectionView`.

Думаю, не надо объяснять, что такое **MVVM**, поэтому для полноты картины я опубликую здесь вспомогательные классы, которые я использовал в решении.

```csharp
// реализация INPC для наследования во ViewModel
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

// реализация ICommand для удобного использования команд
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);
}
```

---

Решение создает демо-коллекцию и позволяет

- Менять количество элементов на страницу
- Переключать страницы

**Полная разметка**

```xaml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:PagerConverter x:Key="PagerConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ItemsPerPage}" Width="40" Margin="5"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Page:" Margin="5,5,0,5"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Page}" Margin="5" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListBox Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5,0" Text="{Binding Index}"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5,0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="2" Margin="3,5">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PagerConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="Items.Count"/>
                    <Binding Path="ItemsPerPage"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding}"
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.SetPageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                            Margin="2" Padding="5,0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Класс для хранения данных**

```csharp
public class Item
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```csharp
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _itemsPerPage;
    private ObservableCollection<Item> _items;
    private int _page;
    private ICommand _setPageCommand;

    private ICollectionView Collection => CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Items);

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
        get => _items;
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Page
    {
        get => _page;
        set
        {
            _page = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            Collection.Refresh(); // сообщает ICollectionView, что надо перефильтроваться
        }
    }

    public int ItemsPerPage
    {
        get => _itemsPerPage;
        set
        {
            _itemsPerPage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            Collection.Refresh();
        }
    }

    public ICommand SetPageCommand => _setPageCommand ?? (_setPageCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        if (parameter is int page)
        {
            Page = page;
        }
    }));

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++)
        {
            Items.Add(new Item { Index = i, Name = $"Element {i}" });
        }
        ItemsPerPage = 15;
        Page = 1;
        Collection.Filter = item => {
            int index = Items.IndexOf(item as Item);
            return index >= (Page - 1) * ItemsPerPage && index < Page * ItemsPerPage;
        };
    }
}
```

**Конвертер для генерации кнопок пейджера**

```csharp
public class PagerConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    // генератор списка с числами по порядку
    private IEnumerable<int> PagesGenerator()
    {
        int i = 1;
        while (true) 
        {
            yield return i++;
        }
    }

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0] is int count && values[1] is int itemsPerPage)
        {
            int pages = count / itemsPerPage + 1;
            return new List<int>(PagesGenerator().Take(pages));
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => null;
}
```

**Выглядит это так**

[image: Пример страниц]

Вот и всё, пробуйте, экспериментируйте. Я не сделал кнопки **Назад** и **Вперед**, но вы можете вставить их в горизонтальную `StackPanel` слева и справа от `ItemsControl` и привязать их к командам, которые делают `Page++` и `Page--`, или к одной команде с параметром.

*На самом деле, я впервые реализовал этот механизм, хоть и много про него слышал, поэтому много рассказать про то, как это работает, не могу. Оно просто работает. :) В коде так же могут быть недочеты, готов их исправить, оставляйте комментарии.*

Comment: Спасибо за пример, очень наглядно! Но главный вопрос всё равно остаётся открытым: я не знаю изначально сколько элементов влезает в ListBox. Размер окна программы ведь может измениться, а также могут быть разные разрешения экрана. Соответственно ItemsPerPage может меняться во время работы программы и зависит от размера области отображения ListBox. Отловить во ViewModel изменение размера LixtBox я могу, прибиндив команду на SizeChanged. Но как мне вытащить VerticalOffset и ViweportHeight из вложенного в listbox ScrollViewer'а и передать/забиндить их на свойства вьюмодели?

Comment: @Alex_Lux а высоту каждого элемента списка мы знаем, или она тоже динамическая?

Comment: Высота всех элементов одинакова и постоянна.

Comment: @Alex_Lux а вы уверены, что это точно нужно? Придется писать обработчики событий, и высчитывать количество элементов для отображения относительно `ListBox.ActualHeight` и передавать это во `ViewModel`, получится не очень сложная, то слегка костыльная реализация. Почему бы просто не совместить достоинства прокрутки `ScrollView`, которые нативно поддерживаются в `ListBox` и постраничного просмотра, который я уже реализовал? К тому же можно где-нибудь в настройках позволить юзеру менять количество элементов, отображаемых на странице, и проблема решена.

Comment: @Alex_Lux единственный вменяемый способ реализации, который я вижу при условии не нарушения MVVM и соблюдения SRP - это `UserControl`, унаследованный от `ListBox`, в котором вместо прокрутки будет высчитываться и ограничиваться количество видимых элементов. Придется в него и постраничную фичу уносить и все параметры постраничного просмотра в `DepencyProperty`. Получится своеобразный `PagedListBox`. Решение весьма комплексное, и я не смогу его быстро реализовать.