# Не обновляется Listview,Как обновить Listview с INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf

На основном экране есть два ListView.

В первом выводится список продукции, во втором корзина. В режиме админа По клику на продукции я могу отредактировать удалить продукции, и список обновляется.

Когда  я добавляю в корзину эту продукцию, список не обновляется. Как сделать, чтобы второй Listview обновлялся?

Вот код класса:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged1;
           //  public IEnumerable<Sale> SaleList { get; set; }
    
          
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                DataContext = this;
                Globals.DataProvider = new MySQLDataprovider();
                ProductType1();
                productMetod();
                productMetod1();
                metodA();
    
            }
    
            private async void productMetod1()
            {
                ProductTypeList = (await Globals.DataProvider.GetProductTypes()).ToList();
              
            }
    
    
                private async void productMetod()
            {
                /*получение товара list*/
                TovarList = await Globals.DataProvider.GetTovar();
            }
    
            private async void ProductType1()
            {
                ProductTypes = await Globals.DataProvider.GetProductTypes();
            }
    
          
    
    
            private async void metod()
            {
                TovarList = await Globals.DataProvider.GetTovar();
            }
            
    
         
            private IEnumerable<Sale> _SaleList;
          
    
            public IEnumerable<Sale> SaleList
            {
                get {
                    var Result = _SaleList;
                return Result;
                } 
                set
                {
                    _SaleList = value;
                    Invalidate1();
                }
            }
    
    
    
            private void ProductListView_MouseDoubleClick_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
            {
               
                var NewSaleWindow = new SaleWindow(ProductListView.SelectedItem as Tovar);
                
    
                if ((bool)NewSaleWindow.ShowDialog())
                {
                    metodA();
                    Invalidate1();
    
    
                }
               
    
            }
    
            private void metodA()
            {
                SaleList = Globals.DataProvider.GetSale();
            }
    
           
//вот этот работает метод и обновляет список
            private void Invalidate()
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TovarList")
                        );
            }
//а вот это не работает
            private void Invalidate1(string ComponentName = "SaleList")
            {
                if (PropertyChanged1 != null)
                    PropertyChanged1(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(ComponentName));
            }
    
            public Sale ChangedProduct11 { get; set; }
           
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Это делается через `ICollectionView`

Comment: спасибо ,можете примерно обьяснить как это делать?

Comment: Здесь можно посмотреть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1131976/373567, плюс познакомьтесь с `ObservableCollection`, для изменяемых списков просто используйте ее вместо `List`.

Comment: спасибо!!!!!!!!

Comment: я попытался применить код к программе ,но у меня все также не обновляется .я впервые про такую функцию  узнал ICollectionView  и ObservableCollection ,но применить  не получается, помогите пожалуйста мне  применить эти функции к моему коду

Comment: А с PropertyChanged,INotifyPropertyChanged не получиться?

Comment: Перестаньте использовать `async void` и все получится, используйте `async Task` и `await`, `async void` только в обработчиках событий уместен, и то не всегда.

Comment: Уберите свой код из конструктора MainWindow, используйте обработчик Window_Loaded вместо этого, ему можно async прописать, и в нем каждому из вызываемых асинхронных методов допишите await а в сигнатуре вызываемых асинхронных методов замените `void` на `Task`. Тогда они будут выполняться последовательно, а не вразнобой. Если надо вразнобой, то есть `await Task.WhenAll(методы)` https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async