# как фильтровать таблицу по поиску?

Tags: c#, wpf

Столкнулся с проблемой, что не понимаю как через textbox сфильтровать таблицу по столбцу фио. Не могу понять, как именно по нужному столбцу это проверять.

```
private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)


{
        var tbx = sender as TextBox;
        if(tbx.Text!="")
        {
            clientGrid.Items[0].Where();
        }
    }
```

это все что я смог. Хотелось бы узнать все же как это сделать.
P.S.
[image: Таблица для фильтрации и ее textbox]

Таблица для фильтрации и ее textbox.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фото с привязкой к столбцам.

```
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        conn.FillGrid(sql, clientGrid);
    }
     string sql = "SELECT fio,bonus_card FROM client ";



public void FillGrid(string sql, DataGrid dataGrid)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (MySqlCommand cmdSel = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdSel);
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                    
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Вам правильно, или абы как? Ибо сейчас у вас ерунда в коде, так не пишут в WPF. Не, ну если хотите, то вам надо переопределить данные "таблицы" (убрать старые и загрузить новые), а условие уж сами смотрите, я по этому коду не понимаю вообще о чем речь, наверно `.Where(x=>x.... == tbx.Text);`. Ну а если правильно, то у вас не должно быть вообще данных в контролах, вы должны разделить все на слои, как минимум данные и UI, а затем привязать их при помощи `Binding` механизмов. Конкретно за фильтрацию данный отвечает `CollectionViewSource`, которому задаете коллекцию и фильтр, а он уже выводит.

Comment: Через  Where оно то и не работает @EvgeniyZ

Comment: Такие штуки делаются через приязки и `ICollectionView`, который можное получить из `CollectionViewSource`. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1131976/373567 здесь есть пример.

Comment: @aepot два столбца у меня привязаны как {Binding fio} и {Binding bonus_card}.

Comment: Пример использования `ICollectionView.Filter` выше.

Comment: @aepot  где пример использования?

Comment: `Через Where оно то и не работает` - мне это не говорит о чем-либо. Повторю, я не понимаю ваш код и вашу задачу. Я не вижу о какой таблице идет речь, я не вижу ее в вопросе; не вижу данных, не вижу, как они поступают в эту таблицу, и так далее. Вот этот вот огрызок `clientGrid.Items[0].Where();` - вообще бесполезный, ибо `Where()` - это получить новый список данных на основе условия, другими словами, `var result = ....Where(x=>x = ...);`, а у вас просто вызывается метод и бросается. причем еще с неким первым объектом, о котором нам тоже ничего не известно. И как мы должны этот костыль решать?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ прошу прощения. Сейчас проверил вопрос и понял что фото и код не загрузился еще.

Comment: Вот вам пример попроще с ICollectionView: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1140841/220553 Советую всеж освоить это.

Comment: прошу прощения, но я не очень понимаю как сделать именно для DataGrid. У меня ListBox нет как в примере, который вы кинули. @EvgeniyZ

Comment: И в чем проблема? Привязки везде одинаковые, без разницы какой контрол используется. Также не понимаю в чем проблема с вашим "костыльным" кодом `dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView.Where(x=>x. условие);`, все (`DefaultView` наверно надо будет привести к классу, который будет содержать в себе свойства).

Comment: Можно использовать `DataView.RowFilter` https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview?view=net-5.0, ему можно задать фильтры, поддерживаемы `DataTable`. @EvgeniyZ мож напишите пример в ответ, хоть с чем-нибудь. Я бы написал, но температура под 39, котелок не варит совсем.

Comment: @aepot по пробовал через DataView.RowFilter. Почему то он берет тип char. Что не подходит для поиска DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql,conn.conn);
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                clientGrid.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView().RowFilter.Where(x=>x=tbx.Text);

Comment: Документацию посмотрите, ссылка выше. Там примеры кода. RowFilter - это string, что вы собрались фильтровать в строке через Where?

Comment: @aepot извиняюсь, но я ничего не нашел в примере с rowfilter. там есть таблица с его описанием и все

Comment: @aepot все я разобрался. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: В таком случае можете опубликовать решение постом ниже, вдруг кому пригодится

Comment: хорошо чуть позже этим займусь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы идете совершенно не правильным, я даже назвал бы наверно "варварским" путем. В WPF принято первым делом использовать XAML и Привязки (Binding). Если вы это не используете, храните данные в тесной связи с UI контролами, то вы получаете очень много проблем (от трудного проектирования, до проблем с производительностью).

Покажу самый простой пример, где будет фильтрация на клиенте, с привязкой.

1. Создадим класс, который будет работать с базой данных, назовем просто `DataBase`. В нем прописываем все методы получения и отправки всех нужных данных, например:

   ```
   public record User(int Id, string Name);

   public class DataBase
   {
       public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers()
       {
           DataTable table = new DataTable();
           table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
           table.Columns.Add("Name");

           table.Rows.Add(1, "Вася");
           table.Rows.Add(2, "Петя");
           table.Rows.Add(3, "Коля");

           return table.AsEnumerable()
               .Select(x => new User(x.Field<int>("Id"), x.Field<string>("Name")));
       }
   }
   ```

   Я здесь эмулировал класс `DataTable` (чтоб его...), с неким набором данных, и привел их к простой коллекции объектов `User` (наш простой класс, который содержит нужные свойства).
2. Дальше создаем класс, который будет источником данных для всего приложения. Пусть зовется `MainViewModel` (почему такие названия, можете почитать про MVVM подход, но сейчас не о нем). В этом классе нам надо получить объект нашей базы данных, создать свойства для привязок, запросить данные из базы. Получаем примерно следующее:

   ```
   public class MainViewModel
   {
       private readonly DataBase data = new();
       public MainViewModel()
       {
           Users = new CollectionViewSource { Source = data.GetAllUsers() }.View;
       }
       public ICollectionView Users { get; }

       private string _searchText;
       public string SearchText
       {
           get => _searchText;
           set
           {
               _searchText = value;
               Users.Filter = x =>
               {
                   var user = x as User;
                   return value.Length > 0 ? user.Name.StartsWith(value) : true;
               };
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Как видите, все просто, мы делаем объект нашей базы данных (в моем случае просто создаю, в вашем наверно надо передать через конструктор или еще что), делаем коллекцию, тип которой `ICollectionView`, связываем их через `CollectionViewSource`. Остается свойство `SearchText` - это простое свойство, которое будет содержать текст, вверенный пользователем в текстовое поле, в его сеттере мы задаем фильтр, некое условие, которое вернет нам `true` (объект надо отобразить) и `false` (объект не стоит отображать). Само условие простое - если у строки 0 символов, то `true`, если больше 0, то ищем по началу имени.
3. Задаем `DataContext` окну, просто пишем в его конструкторе `DataContext = new MainViewModel();`, этого нам будет пока достаточно.
4. Все, данные у нас отвязаны, как видите мы до сих пор не использовали что либо из UI, ибо нам это и не нужно, наш UI должен быть максимально отделен от данных, в этом суть WPF с его MVVM и прочими подходами. Имея все это, мы теперь можем написать XAML, например такой простой:

   ```
   <Grid>
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
           <RowDefinition />
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <Grid Margin="5">
           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
               <ColumnDefinition />
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <TextBlock Text="Фильтровать по человеку:" />
           <TextBox
               Grid.Column="1"
               BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"
               Text="{Binding SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
       </Grid>
       <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" />
   </Grid>
   ```

   Тут я думаю объяснять ничего не надо, кроме всяких `{Binding ...}` - это привязка, через нее мы задаем свойству контрола некое место, от куда он должен забирать данные, например `{Binding Users}`, это `public ICollectionView Users { get; }` из класса, который мы указали как `DataContext` окну. Еще тут интересным может быть `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` - так мы задали привязки когда именно ей обновлять свойство, конкретно `PropertyChanged` означает "Сразу при обновлении", другими словами, привязанное свойство `SearchText` будет получать сразу введенные данные, а не в момент потери фокуса контрола (по умолчанию).

Все, при запуске у нас будут выведены все данные:

[image: All Data]

Ну а если мы напишем что-либо в текстовое поле, нам благополучно отфильтрует все:

[image: Filtet Result]

Вот вам и фильтрация на клиенте в WPF проекте. Но учтите, если у вас идет работа с базой, то фильтрация ее уровень, вы не должны вообще хотеть загружать на клиент **всех** пользователей из базы, это очень ресурсоемкая задача. Поэтому очень продумывайте такие аспекты, если у вас уже готовые данные, которые вы вывели и в них нужна фильтрация - мой пример подойдет, а если данные в базе, и на их основе надо вывести что-то конкретное, то делаете в базу конкретный запрос и выводите уже потом эти данные.