# не корректно сортирует ado c#

Tags: c#, wpf, ado.net

Написал данный запрос для сортировки, вроде все отлично но "test10" влезает не туда, есть идея, что "10" выступает в роли "2" в десятичной системе. Как фиксить? (на счет от А до Я в ComboBox, поменяю...)

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand cmd = null;
            if (v == 1)
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM Product " +
                                                $"ORDER BY name_product ASC", con);
            }
            else if (v == 0)
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM Product " +
                                     $"ORDER BY name_product DESC", con);
            }
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            return dv = dt.DefaultView;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Аналогично [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1450148/220553), только метод не фильтрации, а сортировки. И почему все используют этот несчастный Ado.net не пойму....

Comment: @EvgeniyZ посоветуете что-то лучше? просто единственное, что я смог найти в качестве связи с бд

Comment: Вам для чего? Понять, как писать запросы вручную, обрабатывать их и так далее? Если да, то оставайтесь на ADO.NET, если вам нужно лишь работать удобно с базой, то берите современный EF, который по сути является оберткой над ADO.NET и составляет все запросы грамотно за вас (включая создание базы (миграция) ), вам его лишь грамотно настроить надо. Просто я не знаю, как по мне, люди себя не уважают с ADO.NET) Вместо всего вашего кода можно написать на EF допустим просто `var result = db.Items.OrderBy(x=>x.Name);`, (ну и + парочка классов, которые описывают базу и подключение), все....

Comment: @EvgeniyZ как относитесь к model ado net?

Comment: Всё правильно сортирует. Это же строки. Строка "10" больше "1", но меньше "2".

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov чего? типо разный вес? у "10" больше битов чем у "1", но меньше " 2"?

Comment: Это **не** числа, это строки.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov т.е последний элемент строки '0' является пустым, поэтому получается "test1"?

Comment: Нет. "10" это и есть "10". Строка. Не число. Это в любом языке программирования так. Основы.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20240313/5045688 - тут несколько вариантов

Comment: `order by len(col), col` - хороший способ

Comment: @gwgw `model ado net` - если вы любите ковыряться в XML файликах, создавать кучу лишнего, дерзайте) А я, пожалуй, на EF напишу простой класс, с простыми свойствами и буду работать с базой, как с простой коллекцией)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - между прочим, EF - это часть ADO.NET. [Обзор](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/overview).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я знаю, выше про это и написал (`берите современный EF, который по сути является оберткой над ADO.NET`). Поэтому и удивляюсь, почему люди используют скажем так "низкоуровневые" механизмы, если только для обучения, ок.