# Расскажите про способ как правильно надо делать выборку в таблице в wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

Расскажите или подскажите ,где найти способ про правильное создание таблицы с бд в wpf. Я просто хочу найти источники и почитать как правильно это сделать. Кода пока нет. Хочу написать, но для начала нужно узнать как в datagrid это делать. Прошу совета или помощи.

Comment: К `DataGrid` можно подключить `DataTable` `myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myDataTable.DefaultView;`, с `DataTable` работать можно точно так же как в Winforms.

Comment: Я вам уже [рассказывал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1450148/220553) как правильно, жалко, что тот ответ пошел в пустоту.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ можете пожалуйста привести примеры именно готовые проекты. Просто хочу посмотреть как это работает. Может быть на гитхаб есть или где то ?

Comment: Выше ведь готовый код, готовый пример, чего вы еще хотите я не пойму?) Или вам надо прям "идеальный" вид проекта, понять как такое делается, что надо, и так далее? Если да, то можете посмотреть [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852526/220553) и [вот этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1278817/220553). По уровне сложности - ссылка выше это самое базовое, затем из этого комментария первая - уже посложнее с MVVM подходом, ну а последняя, это уже прям весьма такое, сложное, с MVVM и DI. Найти примеров можно и еще кучу, главное понимать что именно вы хотите.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я хочу разобраться просто. Когда я делал в прошлый раз, у меня было много написано стилей и объектов. Я в них запутался из-за чего и не понял. Сейчас вот хочу разобраться, чтобы делать нормально, а то в прошлый раз костыль вышел

Comment: Вот начните делать, попробуйте сами по примеру выше, поймите суть, а потом приходите сюда с кодом и попросите конкретную помощь, может даже инспекцию кода попросите, вам помогут, расскажут как правильно, что сделали не так. А сейчас, я думаю вы понимаете, что мы болтаем в пустую, ибо я вам уже дал примеры, а вы от меня до сих пор их требуете.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ прошу прощения не хотел вас мучать. Просто хотел поинтересоваться кто знает эту тему и где можно это было бы поучить или посмотреть. Спасибо за пример вам огромное.

Comment: А вы меня и не мучаете) Просто я даю вам совет как лучше поступить, прислушиваться к нему или нет - ваше право. Конкретно прям полноценного, готового приложения, которого будет решать конкретно вашу задачу, такого нет, и быть не может. Все программирование сводится к набору правил, рекомендаций, которые вы должны понять и уже применять их на практике, а когда именно у вас будет проблема с пониманием чего либо, то уже у вас и сформируется конкретный вопрос, на который мы можем дать ответ, сотбственно вот и все чего я хочу до вас донести.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ хорошо спасибо