# Отображение данных (фильтрация)

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

хочу вывести данные в CollectionView, данные которые имеют state = false с использованием CommunityToolkit.Mvvm, но не совсем понимаю как это сделать.

**Model**

```
public class Task
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool State { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <SwipeView Margin="0,0,0,10">
                                <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                                    <SwipeItems Mode="Execute">
                                        <SwipeItem 
                                            Text="Done"
                                            BackgroundColor="LightGreen"
                                            Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:ToDoViewModel}}, Path=StateDoneCommand}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                    </SwipeItems>
                                </SwipeView.LeftItems>

                                <SwipeView.RightItems>
                                    <SwipeItems>
                                        <SwipeItem 
                                            Text="Edit"
                                            BackgroundColor="LightYellow"/>
                                        <SwipeItem 
                                            Text="Delete"
                                            BackgroundColor="LightPink"
                                            Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:ToDoViewModel}}, Path=RemoveCommand}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                    </SwipeItems>
                                </SwipeView.RightItems>

                                <Frame CornerRadius="0">
                                    <VerticalStackLayout Spacing="5">
                                        <Label
                                            Text="{Binding Title}"
                                            FontSize="24"
                                            FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                            <Label
                                                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                                LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                                FontSize="16"
                                                Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                                            <Label
                                                Text="{Binding CreateDate, StringFormat='{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}"
                                                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                                VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                                </Frame>

                            </SwipeView>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public partial class ToDoViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        string title;
        [ObservableProperty]
        string text;
        [ObservableProperty]
        bool state = false;
        [ObservableProperty]
        DateTime createDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
        [ObservableProperty]
        ObservableCollection<Task> tasks;

        int count = 1;
        public ToDoViewModel()
        {
            tasks = new ObservableCollection<Task>();
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        void Add()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                return;
            Task task = new Task
            {
                Title = $"Task #{count}",
                Text = text,
                State = state,
                CreateDate = createDate
            };
            tasks.Add(task);
            count++;
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        void Remove(Task task)
        {
            if (tasks.Contains(task))
                tasks.Remove(task);
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        void StateDone(Task task)
        {
            task.State = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1450148/220553 Внимание на `CollectionViewSource`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо за ваш ответ. Не подскажите какой using, не могу найти, почему-то в 
System.ComponentModel нету его

Comment: мм, а его [нет в MAUI](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3837), чтож, тогда извините)

Comment: Можно прибиндить Visibility элемента к state.