# Как получить значение всех элементов ItemsControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, ado.net

Возникла проблема, имеются множество TextBox-ов, в которых есть значения, все эти TextBox-ы находятся в `ItemsControl`. Необходимо получить значения всех этих TextBox-ов и передать в функцию из другого класса. Пробовал использовать методы `ItemsSource` и `Items`, но при дебаге вижу, что контейнеры `null`.

XAML код:

```
<Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1">
            <ItemsControl x:Name="NFR">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="ID аккаунта" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Foreground="#498C51"/>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="id_account" IsReadOnly="True" Width="200" Height="30" Text="{Binding id_account}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="#498C51" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Foreground="DimGray">
                                        <TextBox.Resources>
                                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </TextBox.Resources>
                                    </TextBox>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel  Margin="0,10">
                                    <TextBlock Text="ID клиента" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Foreground="#498C51"/>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="id_client" IsReadOnly="True" Width="200" Height="30" Text="{Binding id_client}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="#498C51" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Foreground="DimGray">
                                        <TextBox.Resources>
                                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </TextBox.Resources>
                                    </TextBox>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Логин" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Foreground="#498C51"/>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="login" Width="200" Height="30" Text="{Binding login}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="#498C51" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS">
                                        <TextBox.Resources>
                                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </TextBox.Resources>
                                    </TextBox>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel  Margin="0,10">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Пароль" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Foreground="#498C51"/>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="password" Width="200" Height="30" Text="{Binding password}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="#498C51" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS">
                                        <TextBox.Resources>
                                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </TextBox.Resources>
                                    </TextBox>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Имя" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Foreground="#498C51"/>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="name" Width="200" Height="30" Text="{Binding name_}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="#498C51" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS">
                                        <TextBox.Resources>
                                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </TextBox.Resources>
                                    </TextBox>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel  Margin="0,10">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Фамилия" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Foreground="#498C51"/>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="second_name" Width="200" Height="30" Text="{Binding second_name}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="#498C51" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" >
                                        <TextBox.Resources>
                                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </TextBox.Resources>
                                    </TextBox>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Отчество" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Foreground="#498C51"/>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="patronymic" Width="200" Height="30" Text="{Binding patronymic}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="#498C51" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS">
                                        <TextBox.Resources>
                                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </TextBox.Resources>
                                    </TextBox>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="20,0">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Дата рождения" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Foreground="#498C51"/>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="date_birthday_textbox" Width="200" Height="30" Text="{Binding date_birthday}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="#498C51" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS">
                                        <TextBox.Resources>
                                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </TextBox.Resources>
                                    </TextBox>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel  Margin="0,10">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Серия паспорта" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Foreground="#498C51"/>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="seria_passport" Width="200" Height="30" Text="{Binding series_passport}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="#498C51" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS">
                                        <TextBox.Resources>
                                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </TextBox.Resources>
                                    </TextBox>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Номер паспорта" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Foreground="#498C51"/>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="number_passport" Width="200" Height="30" Text="{Binding number_passport}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="#498C51" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS">
                                        <TextBox.Resources>
                                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </TextBox.Resources>
                                    </TextBox>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel  Margin="0,10">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Номер телефона" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Foreground="#498C51"/>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="number_phone" Width="200" Height="30" Text="{Binding number_phone}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="#498C51" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS">
                                        <TextBox.Resources>
                                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </TextBox.Resources>
                                    </TextBox>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Электронная почта" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Foreground="#498C51"/>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="email" Width="200" Height="30" Text="{Binding email}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="#498C51" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS">
                                        <TextBox.Resources>
                                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </TextBox.Resources>
                                    </TextBox>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel  Margin="0,10">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Номер полиса" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Foreground="#498C51"/>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="number_policy" Width="200" Height="30" Text="{Binding number_policy}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="#498C51" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS">
                                        <TextBox.Resources>
                                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </TextBox.Resources>
                                    </TextBox>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
            
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Grid.Row="3" Background="#76E383">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Button x:Name="save" Content="СОХРАНИТЬ" Background="#498C51" Width="130" Height="30" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Margin="0,0,10,0" Click="save_Click" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                    <Button.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="Border">
                            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Resources>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="back" Content="НАЗАД" Background="#498C51" Width="130" Height="30" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Click="back_Click" IsCancel="True" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                    <Button.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="Border">
                            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Resources>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

CS код:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Session1.Classes;

namespace Session1.Pages
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для RedactorClient.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class RedactorClient : Page
    {
        bool rewrite;
        public RedactorClient(string id, int type_polic)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if(id != null)
            {
                rewrite = true;
                NFR.ItemsSource = Load.getDataClient(id);
                comboboxPolicy.SelectedIndex = type_polic;
            }
            else
            {
                rewrite = false;
            }
        }

        private void back_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new MenuAdministator());
        }

        private void save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (rewrite == true)
            {
                Load.saveClient(NFR.ToString(), true);
            }
            else
            {
                Load.saveClient(NFR.ToString(), false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Фоточки дебага:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не храните данные в UI! Вот взять допустим этот сайт, SO, вы видите комментарии, вопросы, и прочее, как думаете, они где хранятся? На сервере в базе, или в HTML, который потом передается клиенту? Я думаю, ответ очевиден. Также и тут, почему вы вдруг хотите в UI, в кнопке, текстбоксе и прочем, сохранить какие-либо данные? Им там место? Нет. Так может стоит начать правильно писать проект, отделить данные от UI? Использовать механизм привязок? Создайте класс, укажите его как `DataContext` окна, в этом классе сделайте публичное свойство коллекции, загрузите туда данные, а в XAML просто привяжите.

Comment: @EvegniyZ я не храню данные в UI, это страница с редактированием записи, туда автоматически должны сунуться данные, сейчас мне крайне срочно нужно решить это методом говна и палок. К сожалению пока что нет времени делать через MVVM

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я использую DataTable для хранения данных и с помощью binding вяжу данные с DataTable , разве это не правильно?

Comment: На скрине вы что делаете? `NFR` это что? Хм наверно `<ItemsControl x:Name="NFR">`? Данные вы от куда достать хотите? `NFR.Items`? `NFR.ToString()` (что за ерунда..?)? Другими словами, вы засунули в контрол данные и теперь с ним работаете, вытягивая из него нужное, когда как у вас должно это быть все раздельно. Даже вопрос у вас звучит `Как получить значение всех элементов ItemsControl`, что сразу  показывает ваши намерения вытягивания данных из UI контрола.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в принципе все верно, фактически я хочу получить массив со значениями из ItemsControl

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я написал `NFR.ToString()` для того, чтобы просто видеть в дебаге. Если я не ошибаюсь, я могу посмотреть содержимое не зависимо от метода, который вызову, будь то `ToString()` или `Items`

Comment: Ну вот это ваша основная проблема, и тут даже дело не в MVVM, я вам не предлагаю его, тут дело в архитектуре проекта, в ООП и прочем, ведь у вас банально один участок делает задачи не предназначенные для него. У вас должно быть как: Делаете публичное свойство с типом данных, например `publi List<Person> Persons { get; private set; }` Дальше вы делаете `Persons = Load.getDataClient(id);`, а где надо взять данные, то вы делаете `var result = Persons....;`. Ну а UI, если не хотите по уму, то `NFR.ItemsSource = Persons;`, ну а по уму привязки, там тогда автоматом обновит все.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вы говорите `Другими словами, вы засунули в контрол данные и теперь с ним работаете, вытягивая из него нужное, когда как у вас должно это быть все раздельно`, как понять раздельно? и как я с ним работаю, максимум для чего мне нужен контрол, засунуть значения в textbox-ы или вытащить если значения поменялись. Разве это не правильно?

Comment: Как видите, в примере выше, идет отделение данных от UI, нет работы с UI контролом, как с источником данных. Вот в этом направлении и надо вам двигаться, а не в "получить значения всех элементов ItemsControl". Ну и привязки, не ленитесь, чтоб они заработали, достаточно задать `DataContext` и в XAML тогда уже писать `<ItemsControl ItemsSource = "{Binding Persons}">`, все...

Comment: `Разве это не правильно?` - вы правильный подход изначально отклонили. Правильный подход, это когда у вас нету вообще `x:Name`, когда вы можете взять и удалить весь XAML и у проекта у вас будет работать без ошибок, когда вы можете заменить весь UI, например на консоль без каких-либо проблем, ну и так далее. Вот это все "Правильный подход". А когда вы работаете с контролами через C# код, это не правильный подход, это нарушение многих правил)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ т.е вы предлагаете отказаться от CS у страниц(окон), все время пилить в xaml, а данные из какого-нибудь класса отдельного

Comment: Могу как пример дать вам [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1450148/220553) ответ. Там и `DataTable` используется, и привязки, и все в этом духе, прям минимальных, хороших пример того, как должно быть. Обратите внимание на то, что там нет ни единого `x:Name`, мой C# код не знает вообще про XAML контролы, но все как видите прекрасно работает.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ пару вопросов по тому ответу 1) что если у вас 1000 записей в бд, я видел там вы создали items-ы, для примера самое то, но у меня бд 2) для работы с таблицей вы используете Linq? 1 вопрос я понял, я буду использовать DataTable

Comment: А это не относится ведь к текущей теме, вы можете там писать что угодно и как угодно. Тут сама суть в подходе проектирования вашего проекта, как и что друг с другом взаимодействует, разделении. Ведь основа любого WPF (и новее) проекта - это XAML и Binding, вот их вам и надо освоить. А работа с базой и прочим, это уже дело десятое, я допустим терпеть не могу Ado.Net, а вы вот используете) Под свои задачи как говорится. Если всеж интересны эти ответы, то 1. Без разницы, вы так или иначе получаете  `DataTable` и его производные. 2. Из LINQ там только `.Select()`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ тогда мне придётся для binding использовать всякие методы, типо INotifyChanged. Есть мануалочки про бинды? ибо я нашел одну, но там как-то не особо подробно

Comment: @EvgeniyZ на счет `x:name` вы кнч не правы, в любом случае нужно использовать, чтобы при создании обработчиков событий, хотя бы понимать, что это за метод ты создал. Может у вас есть аргумент на этот счет?

Comment: Правы или нет, я убеждать не буду, делайте как знаете. Я спокойно пишу кучу проектов и там нет ни единого `x:Name`, нет обработчиков событий, и прочего, это спокойно заменяется привязками, командами и прочими прелестями WPF. Считаете, что я не прав - делайте как знаете, пример я выше дал, который показал, что без контролов проект идеально работает, этого думаю достаточно для доказательств. `INotifyChanged`- он нужен если вы меняете свойство из кода во время работы приложения, достаточно найти любую удобную реализацию в интернете и ее использовать. "Мануал" - могу свои ответы посоветовать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ буду признателен, если накидаете ссылочки

Comment: Мне сложно что либо советовать вам без какой либо конкретики) Ну как минимум, можете начать с [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852526/220553).