# Не выводит данные в ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Users:

```
class Users
    {
        public static DataView User { get; set; }
    }
```

Load:

```
class Load
    {
        private static string connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-DHMQJ5P;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True";
        private static SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        private static SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        private static DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        private static SqlCommand command;
        public static void getUsers()
        {
            try
            {
                using (connection)
                {
                    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter($"SELECT * FROM Users", connection);
                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                    Users.User = dataTable.DefaultView;
                };
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private View.MainWindow mainWindow;
        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            var mainViewModel = new ViewModel.MainViewModel();
            mainWindow = new View.MainWindow { DataContext = mainViewModel };
            MainWindow.Show();
        }
    }
```

MainViewModel:

```
 class MainViewModel
        {
            public MainViewModel()
            {
                Model.Load.getUsers();
            }
        }
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" Width="auto" Height="500" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="auto">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding id, StringFormat='id: {0}'}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name, StringFormat='Имя: {0}'}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding second_name, StringFormat='Фамилия: {0}'}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding patronymic, StringFormat='Отчество: {0}'}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding date_birthday, StringFormat='Дата Рождения: {0}'}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding phone, StringFormat='Телефон: {0}'}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding email, StringFormat='Email: {0}'}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
```

[image: Структура проекта]

UPD:
MainViewModel:

```
public MainViewModel()
        {
            Model.Load.getUsers();
            DataView Users = Model.Users.User;
        }
```

Comment: Содержимое `MainViewModel` где?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ если что ваша разработка, сейчас дополню вопрос

Comment: Запомните одно очень важное правило в привязках каких-либо данных. Когда вы пишете `{Binding Name}` - это `Name` должно быть **публичным свойством**, которое должно находится в классе, который указан как `DataContext`. Вот теперь смотрим, вы пишете `ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"`, то есть ссылаетесь на публичное свойство `Users`, далее смотрим это `DataContext = mainViewModel`, то есть у окна установлен `DataContext` на `MainViewModel`, а значит там должно быть `public ... Users {get; set;}`, где оно? И да, забудьте про статику!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ничего не понял, но очень интересно. Т.е  в классе `Users` я должен написать `public class Users{}`?

Comment: Чего не понятного в `DataContext на MainViewModel, а значит там должно быть public ... Users {get; set;}, где оно?`? Вроде прямым текстом написал кто, что и где должно быть. Если привязываете `ItemsSource`, то ваше свойство должно быть коллекцией, коллекцией пользователей, например `public List<User> Users {get; set;}`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ получается как-то так

Comment: @EvgeniyZ основная проблема, что я использую DataTable для получения таблицы из бд,  и сувать потом DataTable в List тяжело, много строк. Я думал, что в DataContext достаточно прописать вызов метода для получения бд и он получит, но после нескольких попыток перепрочесть ваши слова, я понял, что не так все сделал, в любом случае, сейчас по идеи все работает, но запрос не выводит данные...

Comment: Мой вам совет - откажитесь от ADO.NET и используйте EF, если конечно у вас нет задачи учить SQL запросы. С EF вы будете сразу получать все нужное простыми LINQ запросами (допустим взять из базы всех пользователей, возраст которых больше 10, в EF будут вытягиваться примерно так `var users = db.Users.Where(x=>x.Age > 10);`, как видите, простые запросы, ничего лишнего). Если всеж нужна эта ужасная `DataTable`, то я вроде уже кидал вам [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1450148/220553), где есть конвертация в нормальный класс, много кода? Ну что поделать, таков ADO.NET.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ `var users = db.Users.Where(x=>x.Age > 10);` что такое `x`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1476505/501401 не могли бы глянуть, пожалуйста

Comment: Это зовется лямбдой выражения, некое условие, которое делает метод, где `x` это любое придуманное вами название переменной, которое будет содержать в себе конкретный объект. Допустим у нас есть коллекция `List<User> Users;`, мы пишем `var result = Users.Where(user=>user.Age > 10);`, тогда в этом случае `user` - это объект класса `User` (заметьте, в этот раз я написал не x, а `user`, ну а x это обычно использую как некое стандартное обозначение лямбды.