# Почему мусорит в textblock после выбора элемента из ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock FontSize="30" Text="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=SelectedValue}" FontFamily="Rubik" Foreground="Black" Background="Pink"/>
            <ListView Margin="0,20" x:Name="listView" SelectionMode="Single">
                <ListViewItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="YES" FontSize="30" FontFamily="Rubik"/>
                </ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>
                    <TextBlock Text="NO" FontSize="30" FontFamily="Rubik"/>
                </ListViewItem>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Xaml.cs: Пустая, ничего не добавлял

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы создадите класс, допустим `class Test { public string Name {get;} = "Имя"; }`, потом создадите этот класс `var test = new Test();` и выведите на экран его, допустим `Console.WriteLine(test);`, что увидите на экране? Будет там "Имя" или нечто другое? Ответ естественно - нечто другое, а чтоб вывести на экран имя, нам надо написать `Console.WriteLine(test.Name);`. В C#, если вы что либо отображаете как строку, то это что-то будет преобразовано через `.ToString()` метод в нечто, что прописано в этом классе. Также и в XAML, у вас есть класс `ListViewItem`, внутри которого класс `TextBlock`.

Comment: Хотите нормальный вывод, делайте значит данные без каких либо излишеств, например `<ListView.Items><sys:String>YES</sys:String><sys:String>NO</sys:String></ListView.Items>`, где `sys` вам подскажет как подключить сама студия, у меня лично это `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=netstandard"`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а в чем собсна прикол использовать `sys`? Если допустим я буду украшать текст в `Border` и во всякие контейнеры, то как

Comment: "Прикол" в том, что у вас данные сразу в формате `String`, а не в `new ListViewItem(new TextBlock() { Text = "..." })` (классы написал от балды). Другими словами, в `Items` у вас будет `string [] { "YES", "NO" }`, простой массив строк, не более. Как сделать вид - для этого существует `ItemTemplate`, который и задает вид каждому элементу, например: `<ListView.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate><TextBlock FontSize="30" FontFamily="Rubik" Text="{Binding}"/></DataTemplate></ListView.ItemTemplate>`.

Comment: В вашем `UPD` вы до сих пор используете `ListViewItem`, внимательней смотрите на код, который я вам даю, повторять по сто раз одно и тоже я не собираюсь.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ простите( я не хотел, оно само

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а если в `DataTemplate` есть много-много всякого и нужно вывести некоторые элементы, мне использовать `SelectedItem`?

Comment: Не понял вопроса. `DataTemplate` - это вид объектов, как вы там собрались что либо выводить? Или речь идет про вид для конкретного объекта? В таком случае делится все на разные классы и делается несколько `DataTemplate` с указанием типа, тогда XAML сам будет подставлять нужный вид. И тут мы с вами понимаем, что данные в XAML это плохо, ваши `YES/NO` должны быть в коде (если конечно это не чисто дизайн).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ могу здесь описать или создать вопрос?

Comment: Что конкретно нужно?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ есть `ItemsControl`(который показывает картинку и название) и `ListBox`(с данными). Необходимо при выборе элемента из `ListBox` вывести в `ItemsControl`, я как бы прописал бинд, но ничего не выводит, хотя везде `DataTemplate` и как я понял, с `SelectedItem` не должно быть проблем. После пытался програмно(насильно) воткнуть, и увидел, что `DataRowView` низя в `Collection.IEnumerable`. В итоге поменял на ту стринг, но вывод `ссылка на объект.....`

Comment: Эм... А как это все связано друг с другом? `ItemsControl` - это аналог `ListBox`, только без выделения, он у вас как говорите "показывает картинку и название", ок, а зачем для показа этого, использовать элемент, предназначенный для отображения коллекции? Предположу, что вам нужно [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/816149/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ это кнч круто, но указывать у каждого элемента бинд....хотелось бы с помощью бинда `ItemsSource` решить проблему

Comment: Значит вы делаете что-то не то, раз вам надо каждому элементу задавать бинд. В программировании повторение - это первый признак того, что идет что-то не так. Я не могу вам слепо советовать что либо, все нужные примеры дал, больше, как бы, извиняйте.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ понял, принял, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock FontSize="30" Text="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=SelectedItem}" FontFamily="Rubik" Foreground="Black" Background="Pink"/>
            <ListView Margin="0,20" x:Name="listView" SelectionMode="Single">
                <ListView.Items>
                    <sys:String>YES</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>NO</sys:String>
                </ListView.Items>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]