# Поиск по DataGrid относительно RadioButton

Tags: mysql, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid, radiobutton

Всем привет. Есть DataGrid, подгружаемая из SQL, в которую запихнуты данные из таблиц Goods и Categories. По полю Title из Goods при выбранном RadioButton ищет спокойно, а вот по полю Name_Category из таблицы Categories не хочет. Прилагаю код:

```
private void Search_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (OnTitle.IsEnabled)
        {
            var query = from TitleTovar in context.Goods
                        where TitleTovar.Title.Contains(Search.Text)
                        select TitleTovar;
            GoodsGrid.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
        }
        else if (OnCategory.IsEnabled)
        {
            var query = from Tovar in context.Goods
                        join Category in context.Categories
                         on Tovar.ID_Category equals Category.ID_Category
                        where Category.Name_Category.Contains(Search.Text)
                        select Tovar;
            GoodsGrid.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Хм, а зачем так сложно? `var query = context.Goods.Where(x=>x.Title == Search.Text);`, ну и `var query = context.Goods.Include(x=>x.Category).Where(x=>x.Category?.Name_Category == Search.Text);`, вроде более лаконичный, и понятный запрос, нет? Ну а так, смотрите сами под отладкой, что получаете, что ищите, имеется-ли это в базе с таким названием, и так далее. Отладка у программиста - это один из самых основных инструментов!

Comment: К сожалению не работает, полностью все данные пропадают при таких запросах :(

Comment: Ну, первый точная копия вашего запроса, который вы говорите, что работает. Со вторым я особо не знаком, но в интернете говорят, что работать должен. Можете попробовать чуть иначе, передав условие в `Include`, что-то вроде этого `var query = context.Goods.Include(c=>c.Category.Where(x=>x.Name_Category == Search.Text));`, но тут я правда не знаю как отработает... Увы и ах, базы под рукой нет, проверить не могу. Как один из вариантов, могу вам предложить [фильтрацию на клиенте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1450148/220553), но это если данных очень мало и проект "чисто для теста".

Answer (score 0):

Вот это всё решило:

```
 private void Search_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool)OnTitle.IsChecked)
        {
            var query = from TitleTovar in context.Goods
                        where TitleTovar.Title.Contains(Search.Text)
                        select TitleTovar;
            GoodsGrid.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
        }
        else if ((bool)OnCategory.IsChecked)
        {
            var query = from Tovar in context.Goods
                        join Category in context.Categories
                         on Tovar.ID_Category equals Category.ID_Category
                        where Category.Name_Category.Contains(Search.Text)
                        select Tovar;
            GoodsGrid.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
        }
    }
```