# Сортировка DataGrid

Tags: avalonia

неприятный баг после сортировки DataGrid,
`foreach (build.trafexcel c in this.list1.ItemsSource)`  обход не будет выполняться по сортировке в ItemsSource, он пойдет по неотсортированной дорожке и значит поиск обходом не получится . Есть ли возможность сделать какой-нибудь `find(blabla)` ? Кроме того `SqlCommand` не понимает в селекте Sql `rtrim(blabla)` приходится делать `readers.GetString(2).TrimEnd()`, кроме того не сортируется `DataGridTemplateColumn`  и как я думаю это только начало , офигеть .

Comment: `обход не будет выполняться по сортировке в ItemsSource` - потому что вы не должны хотеть этого делать. У вас должны быть привязки, где UI максимально отделен от данных, а вот уже с данными вы и должны работать. Также не забывайте, что есть 2 сортировки - UI и "Бекенд", где первая делается например [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1450148/220553) - в этом случае пользователь получает условно 100 продуктов, из которых на экран выводится только, допустим, молоко, нужное ему. Вторая делается уже при получении данных, самое банальное `Items = new()`, где `new` это получение только "молоко"

Comment: @EvgeniyZ , да наверно вы правы вот  только сомневаюсь что этот подход на все случаи жизни . У меня регистратуры работают два десятка лет читая базу только при запуске программы , сто тысяч приблизительно полторы две секунды читается и весь день поиск только в памяти и поиск очень накрученный , я значительно проиграю в скорости при другом подходе . А поиск в гриде не работает как надо , допустим в гриде 20 ивановых и если при поиске программа встанет на пятого иванова, а не на первого, то это ну очень не красиво , а фильтровать только ивановых не правильно потому что ошибки в буквах.