# Как правильно реализовать MVVM WPF на конкретном примере

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Суть: У меня есть модель одиночного объекта, я точно знаю, что я буду использовать коллекции этих объектов в нескольких ViewModel, а сами данные для этих коллекций будут получаться из базы данных. Правильно ли будет создать еще одну модель, которая будет содержать в себе коллекцию и методы взаимодействия с ней или сделать просто static класс с теми же методами, а сами коллекции объявлять в ViewModels? Или оба мои варианта не верны и есть третий путь?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Не надо `static`, сделайте модель. Изучите паттерны Синглтон и Инверсия управления, будет легче с MVVM работать.

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделаю, просто хотел убедиться, что это правильно

Comment: Например, тут есть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/616413/10105

Answer (score 0):

https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.1.php

Тут довольно не плохо объясняют, как пользоваться MVVM.
От себя могу сказать, что `View` и `Model` никогда не общаются друг с другом это происходит через `ViewModel` , это вместо контроллера , `ViewModel` обычно и связывает модель и представление  , в конструкторе класса Вашего представления просто указывается с какой моделью представления то есть `ViewModel` вы связываетесь.

Здесь есть пример кода.

https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.2.php

Comment: ответ ссылкой здесь не очень приветстввуется. Ссылка может стать нерабочей через день, два, месяц, год. И тогда ответ будет бесполезным.

Comment: Про связь View и Model я понимаю, вопрос в том, стоит ли создавать отдельную модель, которая описывает коллекцию объектов первой модели и методы взаимодействия с этой коллекцией? Этот вопрос у меня возник, когда я осознал, что мне потребуется работать именно с коллекией и именно в нескольких ViewModel которые обслуживают несколько View. В примерах, что вы скинули нет отета на мой вопрос, а только общая информация о паттерне MVVM на элементарных примерах.