# Запуск класса перед формой WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне нужно перед запуском mainwindow.xaml запустить класс start.cs. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Есть App.xaml. Нужно пойти в code-behind и там класс App и в нем переопределить protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e). В которой можно делать что угодно и в конце вручную инстанцировать MainWindow и показать ее Show()

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/10105

Answer (score 2):

В файле App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    //И тут делаете всё, что вам надо.
}
```

Comment: Если попытаться вывести MessageBox, то он открывается на пару секунд потом закрывается и появляется форма mainwindow.

Comment: @FAR747, обязательно MessageBox? Вы можете сделать окно на подобие, да ещё и логики своей навесить. А если в общих чертах, для чего вам MessageBox перед открытием основного окна?

Comment: Потому что окно надо тоже вручную показывать, а не через StartupUri, как по умолчанию