# ViewModel - одна или несколько вложенных

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Имеется (c# wpf) окно, в котором динамически показываются разные контролы (фреймы). Набор показываемых контролов определяется в главной vm. Каждый контрол отвечает за работу с отдельным API. В окне может быть несколько контролов одного типа. Данные между разными контролами (в т.ч. одного типа) не пересекаются. Главное окно (vm) отвечают только за состояние (show/hide) контролов.

Между собой контролы по данным не пересекаются. 
Набор и количество контролов фиксированы. Динамического создания и размещения не происходит.

Вопрос где размещать vm данные для контролов.

Вариант 1: Все в одной vm. Тогда как описать массив контролов одного вида?

Вариант 2: Для каждого контрола своя полноценная vm. С `INotifyPropertyChanged`, установкой `DataContext` и т.д.

Вариант 3: Для контрола создается класс vm (напр `Type1ViewModel`), а в главной vm что-то типа `Type1ViewModel[]`

И как следствие вопрос, как в разметке (ну или в главной vm) назначать `DataContext`?

Comment: Правильным является вариант №2 - для каждого контрола своя полноценная vm. В чем проблема с DataContext> просто приравнять этому свойству нужный класс с VM: `DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}"` или `new UserControl() { DataContext = new ViewModel() }`

Comment: @Alex Krassне `DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}"` катит, тк не `static`. А вопрос не как, а как лучше (правильно).

Comment: Ресурсы могут быть статическими и динамическими. Статические ресурсы устанавливается только один раз, а динамические ресурсы могут меняться в течение работы программы. Я не думаю, что  вы собираетесь жонглировать контекстом в течении выполнения программы, подменяя его)) Поэтому StaticResource.

Comment: Как правильно уже сказано, каждому контролу свой полноценный VM. А каким способом назначать DataContext уже не важно, можно в разметке если позволяет структура, можно в главной VM. Обычно в главной VM назначается, но иногда главная VM может отсутствовать за ненадобностью и тогда через разметку: к примеру если окно состоит из множества таб-панелей.

Comment: @AlexKrass: Контрол не должен назначать себе VM. Во-первых, слишком много ответственности, во-вторых, вы не сможете при этом легко связывать разные VM.

Comment: @VladD я вроде нигде этого не писал, но на всякий случай уточняю, что прописывание в XAML контекста должно задаваться из разметки основного окна, а не из разметки контрола. Тогда связь получается слабой и не плодит сущностей, разрывается при необходимости выносом в главную VM в виде свойства: `<MyApiControl DataContext="{StaticResource MyApiVM}"/>`.

Comment: @AlexKrass: Простите, неверно вас понял. У меня немного другой подход обычно, VM не инстанциируется в разметке, и поэтому не доступно в виде `StaticResource` (это позволяет связать разные экземпляры VM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:
для каждого из контролов — своя полноценная VM. В конце-концов, у них разные методы работы, так что вам нужны разные типы. Если вам нужно поместить их в общий контейнер, пускай они реализуют общий интерфейс.

`DataContext` правильно назначать так. Главная VM создаётся не в разметке, а внешним кодом. Лучше всего для этого [подходит `App.xaml.cs`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/10105). Там вы создаёте главную VM, главное окно, и устанавливаете ему `DataContext`. Смысл этого в том, что вы не всегда можете правильно отконфигурировать главную VM конструктором без параметров.

Вложенные VM для контролов должны быть доступны через главную VM как свойства (или как свойство-коллекция, например).

Раздачу вложенных VM контролам переложите на `MainWindow`. У вас должен быть код наподобие

```
<MyApiControl DataContext="{Binding MyApiVM}"/>
```

в главном окне.

Comment: "Вложенные VM для контролов должны быть доступны через главную VM как свойства".  Это как организовать? Через задание имен контролов? - Нельзя. При старте программы (в `App.xaml.cs`) и создании главной ВМ - так ведь вначале создам окно и лежачие на нём контролы (с привязкой), а только потом свяжу окно и ВМ.

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev: `class MainVM { public ControlVM { get; } }`, например.

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev: Что именно нельзя и почему?

Comment: Через задание имен контролов? - Будет привязка ВМ к разметке (а ВМ не должна зависеть от разметки)

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev: Эээ, а где в моём ответе задание имён контролов в VM? У меня задаются только имена VM.

Comment: Виноват. Это я что-то перепутал. Но остается привязка к еще неопределенным дочерним вм.

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev: А почему неопределённым? Вполне определённым вроде.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70554/discussion-between-leonid-malyshev-and-vladd).