# Как в DataTemplate ItemsControl'a поместить UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Есть `ItemsControl`, если в его `DataTemplate` посетить разметку все работает отлично.

Привязка данных:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:LogCollectionViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Сам `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllJournal.AllEvents}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Margin="0 0 2.5 2.5" Height="200"
        Width="300">
                <Grid>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="175"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.RowSpan="2"
                   Fill="White"
                   Opacity="0.5"/>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="125"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Text="{Binding RecordNo}"
                       Style="{StaticResource TextBlockMainStyle}"/>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Text="{Binding Time}"
                       ToolTip="Время события"
                       Style="{StaticResource TextBlockMainStyle}"/>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Text="{Binding Date}"
                       ToolTip="Дата события"
                       Style="{StaticResource TextBlockMainStyle}"/>

                    </Grid>

                    <local:SignalEventView Grid.Row="1"/>

                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Но если весь код из `DataTemplate` вынести в отдельный `UserControl` и в `DataTemplate` добавить только ссылку на этот `UserControl`, то все перестает работать.

Пример:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:LogEventView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Разметка LogEventView:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:LogEventVM/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/LogEventStyle.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Border Margin="0 0 2.5 2.5" Height="200"
        Width="300">
    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="175"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.RowSpan="2"
                   Fill="White"
                   Opacity="0.5"/>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Text="{Binding RecordNo}"
                       Style="{StaticResource TextBlockMainStyle}"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Text="{Binding Time}"
                       ToolTip="Время события"
                       Style="{StaticResource TextBlockMainStyle}"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Text="{Binding Date}"
                       ToolTip="Дата события"
                       Style="{StaticResource TextBlockMainStyle}"/>

        </Grid>

        <local:SignalEventView Grid.Row="1"/>

    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Скриншоты:

Если разметка напрямую в `DataTemplate`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если в DataTemplate вставить `<local:LogEventView/>`, то появляется только количество событий, но с нулевыми данными:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить данный вопрос? Так как разметки будет очень много, и оставлять все о одном `UserControl` не целесобразно.

Comment: Что значит `все перестает работать`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP при обновлении коллекции создается правильное количество экземпляров, но они пустые, без данных, просто отрисованы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в этом:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:LogCollectionViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Контрол **никогда** не имеет права устанавливать себе ViewModel, хуже того — создавать её. Уберите это, должно по идее работать.

Comment: а как тогда привязать данные? Как контрол поймет откуда брать данные?

Comment: Если убрать этот код, то коллекция не обновляется...

Comment: А контролу должны эти данные дать снаружи. Откуда он знает, какой именно экземпляр ему нужен?

Comment: «то коллекция не обновляется» — а можно подробнее? Что вы делаете и что происходит.

Comment: ItemsControl содержит список событий журнала.
Для этих событий есть отдельная ViewModel - LogEventView, которая привязана к LogEventVM (привязывал так же, как и в самом вопросе, только к LogEventVM ).
ItemsControl находится внутри LogCollectionView.
Если в DataTemplate вставить просто ссылку на LogEventView, то коллекция обновляется и показывает количество событий, но сами события "пустые". Если же вставить разметку напрямую, все работает отлично.

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Угу, а всё же что вы делаете, что происходит, и что вы хотели бы, чтобы происходило?

Comment: если отвязать привязку данных, то коллекция не обновляется вообще.

Comment: А вы передаёте _снаружи_ данные в ваш **внешний** `UserControl`? (Я правильно угадал, у вас их два?)

Comment: спасибо большое, вы были правы! Нужно отвязать данные, но видимо я не так все объяснил сначала, данные нужно отвязывать во вложенном UserControl! Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Пожалуйста! Но мне кажется, данные правильнее передавать предавать снаружи и во внешний `UserControl` тоже. Подумайте, это обычно правильный подход.

Comment: а можете скинуть ссылку на правильную реализацию? А то в разных источниках и примерах все по своему делают...

Comment: На мой вкус, правильно так: (1) Окно получает от создающего кода корневую VM (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/10105). (2) Вложенные контролы получают VM как Binding к свойствам корневой VM.