# C# WPF. Как открыть нужное окно приложения в зависимости от размера рабочего стола

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте. Есть приложение на WPF. Хочу добавить два главных окна с различными XAML разметками. Теперь мне нужно запускать приложение в зависимости от размера рабочего стола компьютера/ноутбука.

Как определить ширину и высоту рабочего стола я знаю, делается примерно так:

```
int Width = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width;
int Height = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Height;
```

А вот как реализовать запуск нужного главного окна приложения я не знаю. Возможно ли такое вообще сделать или нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно.

Откройте `App.xaml` и уберите установку свойства `StartupUri`.

Затем откройте `App.xaml.cs` и добавьте в него метод:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    ...
}
```

Вместо многоточия просто проверьте свои условия, создайте экземпляр нужного окна и покажите его:

```
Window window = (условие) ? new Window1() : new Window2();
window.Show();
```

Comment: Я бы ещё дописал `window.DataContext = new MainVM();` перед `window.Show();`. Но да, это в стороне от темы вопроса[.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/10105)

Comment: Вроде бы как получилось. Есть один вопрос к вам: получается, что если я в приложении буду использовать два главных окна, то мне придётся некоторые куски кода дублировать? http://ibb.co/iBBWT7 — вот например здесь. Если в двух словах, то у меня есть другие окна приложения и в конструктор этих окон я в качестве аргумента метода передаю объект главного окна приложения. Если вдруг что-то непонятное сказал, попробую объяснить по-другому.

Comment: @Cuurjol, если вы реализуете шаблон MVVM, то вам не придется дублировать логику, она будет внесена в другие классы

Comment: Понял. Благодарю вас за ответы на мои вопросы.