# При помощи каких средств можно сделать отображение сообщений как в outlook?

Tags: c#, wpf

Меня интересует как можно сделать отображение сообщений как в outlook,т.е есть список и отображается какая-то информация,например отправитель,тема,когда было отправлено, и только по нажатию на само сообщение видно оно целиком.
Если важно:сообщения я получаю при помощи ImapClient(нужно именно его использовать по заданию).Пример того,чего я хочу добиться в итоге, на картинке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Покажу простейший пример подобного функционала...

### Данные

- Для начала создадим модель нашего сообщения, пусть там будет информация об авторе, дата, ну и сам текст:

  ```
  public class MessageModel
  {
      public MessageModel(string autor, DateTime date, string text)
      {
          Autor = autor;
          DateTime = date;
          Text = text;
      }

      public string Autor { get; set; }
      public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
      public string Text { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Далее создадим коллекцию, которая будет содержать наши сообщения, пусть это будет в `MainWindow`, прям в самом начале класса пишем:

  ```
  public ObservableCollection<MessageModel> Messages { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MessageModel>();
  ```
- В конструкторе `MainWindow()` заполним нашу коллекцию и зададим `DataContext`:

  ```
  public MainWindow()
  {
      InitializeComponent( );

      Messages.Add(new MessageModel("User 1", DateTime.Now, "Привет мир!"));
      Messages.Add(new MessageModel("User 2", DateTime.Now, "Хочу кушать...."));

      DataContext = this;
  }
  ```
- Все, простейшие данные для привязки у нас есть, осталось реализовать интерфейс.

### Интерфейс

- Создадим `Grid`, который будет разделять наше пространство на 2 колонки:

  ```
  <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


  </Grid>
  ```
- В левой части пусть будет отображение всех сообщений и возьмем только автора и дату. Для этого нам надо задать шаблон `ItemTemplate`. Также, мы уже сейчас можем указать привязку, `ItemsSource`:

  ```
  <ListBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <StackPanel>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Autor}"/>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateTime}"/>
              </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
  ```
- В левую часть, давайте поместим сверху автора, дату, а снизу пусть все пространство будет занято сообщением. Ну а также, давайте привяжем все элементы к выбранному элементу нашего списка, делается это очень просто! Все элементы мы привязываем как обычно, но только с указанием еще имени нашей коллекции, то есть вот так: `{Binding Messages/Autor}`, а также у нашего `ListBox` надо указать `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"`. Таким образом при клике на объект в `ListBox` мы будем видеть нужные данные в левой части:

  ```
  <Grid Grid.Column="1">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
          <RowDefinition/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Messages/Autor}"/>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Messages/DateTime}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
      </StackPanel>

      <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Messages/Text}"/>
  </Grid>
  ```

Вся разметка целиком у нас получится такая:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Autor}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateTime}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Messages/Autor}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Messages/DateTime}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Messages/Text}"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

### Проверка

[image: result]

p.s. тут много чего нету, вам как минимум еще нужно будет реализовывать INotifyPropertyChanged да и много чего еще. Но на первое время, думаю вполне подходящий вариант. Удачи!

---

> Менять элементы в listbox при смене combobox

Тут все по сути тоже самое:

- В наш класс MessageModel добавим для теста коллекцию, пусть это будет обычный `string[]` с названием TestCollection. Тогда наш класс превратится в что то на подобии этого:

  ```
  public class MessageModel
  {
      public MessageModel(string autor, DateTime date, string text, string[] testCollection)
      {
          Autor = autor;
          DateTime = date;
          Text = text;
          TestCollection = testCollection;
      }

      public string Autor { get; set; }
      public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
      public string Text { get; set; }
      public string[] TestCollection { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Далее допишем заполнение данных:

  ```
  Messages.Add(new MessageModel("User 1", DateTime.Now, "Привет мир!", new[] {"aaa", "bbb"}));
  Messages.Add(new MessageModel("User 2", DateTime.Now, "Хочу кушать....", new[] { "111", "222" }));
  ```
- Дальше для примера перепишем немного разметку (заменим левый ListBox на ComboBox, а в правую часть заместо текста выведем наш `string[]`):

ComboBox я перепишу по топорному из уже имеющегося ListBox:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Autor}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateTime}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Ну а справа TextBox давайте заменим (для примера) на ListBox, который будет привязан к нашему `string[]`:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages/TestCollection}"/>
```

- Вот собственно и все, мы вывели привязали ComboBox и его внутреннюю коллекцию привязали к другому ListBox. Проверим:

[image: result2]

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ
Вы писали: **`p.s. тут много чего нету, вам как минимум еще нужно будет реализовывать INotifyPropertyChanged... да и много чего еще`**
**1.** **Вопрос:** не могли бы вы перечислить перечень, что ещё требуется? Просто ключевые слова...

Comment: @eusataf А зависит от того, что требуется) Каждый проект ведь уникальный, каждый требует что-то свое. Например большинство проектом пишутся по правилам MVVM, а в вопросе я их грубо нарушаю, задавая `DataContext` и данные в конструкторе окна, когда как данные должны быть в отдельном классе (может вообще в базе, а значит нужен для нее отдельно Model/ViewModel слои), а `DataContext` должен быть задан [за пределами окна](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553). INPC тут также нету, данные не будут обновлены при редактировании через код.  Остальное все по желанию.