# Менять элементы в listbox при смене combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Есть классы

```
    public class Project{
         public  string Name{get;set}
         public  ObservableCollection<Task> Tasks {get;set;}=new ObservableCollection<Task>();
        }

   public  class Task
    {
     public  string Name{get;set}
    }
```

Все это обернуто вот в такую вьюху:

```
public class ProjectView : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    ObservableCollection<Project> _projects;
    public ObservableCollection<Project> Projects
    {
        get => _projects;
        set
        {
            _projects = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Projects");
        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Вьюха подключена к ComboBox таким образом:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="projectBox"  Margin="210,84,408,378"  ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" DisplayMemberPath="ProjectName"/>
```

ListBox описал вот так:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="236" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190" Margin="53,162,0,0"  ItemsSource="{Binding Projects/Tasks}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Контекст присваиваю прямо в конструкторе окна:

```
   ProjectView pv = new ProjectView();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = pv;
        }
```

Но ничего не происходит при переключении...

Как мне задать XAML разметку для ListBox, что бы там отображался список Task.Name по конкретному проекту, который сейчас выбран в `ComboBox`?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76429/discussion-on-question-by-iluxa1810----listbox---combobox).

Answer (score 0):

Как сделать, я подробно расписал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/816149/220553).

А что касается конкретно вашей проблемы, то тут вы забыли указать `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` к элементу, который будет оповещать при выборе того или иного значения (то есть ComboBox).