# Привязка элементов в ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Не могу понять, где у меня ошибка с привязкой элементов к `ComboBox`.

Вот такая XAML разметка элемента:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="projectBox"  Width="120" RenderTransformOrigin="1.681,1.246" Margin="210,84,476,378" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" DisplayMemberPath="ProjectName"/>
```

В классе:

`MainWindow объявлено` свойство

```
 public ObservableCollection<ProjectInfo> Projects { get; set; }
```

По нажатию на кнопку вызывается метод, который что-то делает и присваивает этому свойству реальную коллекцию элементов.

В дебаггере я перепроверил и там есть элементы, но по факту в ComboBox ниего не отображается.

Где я ошибся?

**UPD**

Переделал все вот в такой вид:

XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="projectBox"  Margin="210,84,408,378"  ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" DisplayMemberPath="ProjectName"/>



public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ProjectView pv = new ProjectView();
        DataContext = pv;
    }
```

Вьюха:

```
   public class ProjectView : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        ObservableCollection<ProjectInfo> _projects;
        public ObservableCollection<ProjectInfo> Projects
        {
            get => _projects;
            set
            {
                _projects = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Projects");
            }
        }

        public ProjectView()
        {
            Projects = new ObservableCollection<ProjectInfo>
            {
                new ProjectInfo() {ProjectId = 1, ProjectName = "123"},
                new ProjectInfo() {ProjectId = 2, ProjectName = "123"}
            };
        }
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Есть 2 элемента в ComboBox, но названия элементов не видно.

Comment: `public ObservableCollection<ProjectInfo> Projects` - это не свойство, это поле. У свойства есть геттеры/сеттеры

Comment: @tym32167, подправил

Comment: Биндинг работает со свойствами, не с полями. С полями биндинг не работает.

Comment: Поменял на свойство, но все равно не работает=(

Comment: При присвоении этому свойству коллекции элементов вы вызываете NotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: А вы не забыли установить DataContext?

Comment: @tym32167, нет.

Comment: так вызовите, иначе как вы оповестите UI о том, что модель изменилась

Comment: @tym32167, обновил вопрос.

Comment: можно увидеть класс `ProjectInfo`?

Comment: А может в ProjectInfo поля вместо свойств? Или нету public?

Comment: @VladD, да... Подправил и все заработало. Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста! Коллективно разобрали проблему

Comment: @VladD, вопрос, наверное, мне в мусорку отправить?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Лучше написать к нему ответ, проблема-то часто встречается

Comment: @VladD, еще вопрос. А если у меня внутри ProjectInfo есть еще одна коллекция и я хотел бы ее забиндить на ListBox. Т.е меняя ComboBox переключать ListBox. Как это будет выглядеть?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Тут недавно как раз был вопрос на эту тему, сейчас найду. // А, это ваш же: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/817018/10105