# Почему WPF зарезает элементы?

Tags: c#, wpf

Дизайнер все красиво показывает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На выходи выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде, в XAML ничего криминаль

```
<Label Content="Выбор проекта" Margin="40,84,633,378"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="projectBox"  Margin="220,84,398,378"  ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" DisplayMemberPath="ProjectName" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

Comment: `Margin="40,84,633,378"` - прекратите это! Используйте панели! И не надо рисовать контролы мышкой, пишите разметку вручную. Уверен, проблем с непомещающимися контролами больше не будет.

Comment: Вот вы и поплатились за это... А я [предупреждал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/817018/Менять-элементы-в-listbox-при-смене-combobox?noredirect=1#comment1299676_817018))

Comment: @АндрейNOP, В WinForms вроде это работало =)

Comment: @iluxa1810, ну здесь другие принципы, другой подход.

Comment: Но тем не менее, интересно отличие в смысле маргинов между WinForms и WPF.

Comment: @iluxa1810: А какой контейнер? `Grid`?

Comment: @VladD, да. Все по дефолту.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Ну контейнеры могут быть и вложенными (и это обычная вещь в WPF), так что Grid — не то, чтобы дефолтный контейнер.

Comment: Кстати, для отображения простых текстовых блоков используется TextBlock, а не Label, Label более тяжеловесный и вообще может отображать любой контент (хоть картинку, хоть кнопку, хоть грид с десятком текстовых полей), собственно у него свойство и называется Content, а не Text, как у TextBlock

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У WPF всё устроено просто. Когда `Grid` пытается разместить ваши элементы, он из области, в которой должен быть расположен ваш элемент (если у вас нет ни `ColumnDefinitions`, ни `RowDefinitions`, то это весь `Grid`) вычитает слева 220 и справа 378, и в этой области пытается разместить элемент. Если оставшаяся область получается слишком маленькой, то элементу, понятно, даётся очень мало места, и он обрезается в отведённом месте. Вы можете легко увидеть это, потягав окно за правый нижний угол, чтобы оно меняло свои размеры.

Поведение у WinForms, судя по всему, не такое.

---

В WPF вам очень редко должно хотеться использовать `Margin` для размещения элементов. Он должен использоваться только по прямому назначению: задавать небольшой визуальный отступ от края положенной области. К сожалению, при использовании встроенного дизайнера Студии расположение элементов часто устанавливается при помощи именно `Margin`.

Правильный UI пишется на XAML'е вручную. (И если вы думаете, что вначале и через дизайнер покатит, то это не так, пишите вручную сразу.)

Для вашего случая может подойти что-то такое:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5">
        <Label Content="Выбор проекта" DockPanel.Dock="Left" MaxWidth="150"/>
        <ComboBox Margin="10,0,0,0" />
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Результат:

[image: анимашка]

Comment: А какой прогой вы такие гифки делаете?

Comment: @iluxa1810: [LICEcap](https://www.cockos.com/licecap/), нашёл ссылку на его в каком-то ответе на SO :)

Comment: Да, в формах положение определяет Location, а Margin ощутимо работает у контролов, которые размещаются внутри контейнеров с автоматическим выравниванием и размещением контента, вроде FlowLayoutPanel и TableLayoutPanel. В остальных случаях игнорируется. Ну дизанер еще его учитывает. когда подсказки по выравниванию показывает.

Comment: @rdorn зато в формах есть якори (Anchor), и если включить все четыре - будет такое же поведение :-) // cc:VladD

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Интересно. Но ТС по идее задаётся вопросом, почему такие же, как и в WinForms, маргины ведут себя в WPF по-другому.