# Как остановить самозацикленную функцию?

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть функция которая запускается кнопкой старт и сама себя бесконечно воспроизводит через `root.after()`

Нужно сделать кнопку `stop`, которая будет останавливать эту функцию, при этом не удаляя, чтобы можно было кнопкой старт ее снова запустить.

Как это реализовать?

Менять `root.after()` на обычный цикл который останавлиаается через `break` не нужно.

```
def a(event):
    def b():
        global x

        print x
        x += 1
        root.after(100, b)
    b()
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос (через кнопку `править`) пример этой функции. Простой набросок без логики. А так, наверное, без какого-нибудь флага не обойтись. Типо `if flag: root.after()`, и откуда-то вы его меняете на `False`, и функция остановится

Comment: ``while (not stop):`` и далее код

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот пример подсчета значение каждую секунду при нажатии на кнопку. При нажатии на стоп вы замораживаете отсчет до тех пор пока не нажмете кнопку старт.
[Как пример таймер обратного отсчета.](https://github.com/Cmertho/Python_project/blob/master/timer/timer_tkinter.py)

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk # python 2.x
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    import tkinter as tk # python 3.x


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.second = 0
        self.label = tk.Label(text="Прошло времени: {} сек".format(self.second))
        self.label.pack()

        button_start = tk.Button(text="Нажать чтобы начать отсчет", command=self.start).pack()
        button_stop = tk.Button(text="Остановить отсчет", command=self.stop).pack()

    def start(self):
        self.second += 1
        self.label.config(text="Прошло времени: {} сек".format(self.second))
        self.time = self.after(1000, self.start)

    def stop(self):
        if self.time is not None:
            self.after_cancel(self.time)
            self.time = None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
    main.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чем вы сделали такую гифку? поделитесь утилитой, если она не очень ценная

Comment: @nick_n_a сам вчера [нашел](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/817738/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-wpf-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b/817764#comment1300081_817764)

Comment: Спасибо, оказалось все очень легко, просто я не думал, что можно присваивать переменную этой команде)