# Кто должен быть ответственен за это?

Tags: c#, wpf

В общем, есть перечень классов [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/817018/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-listbox-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5-combobox).

Вьюху я забиндил на `ComboBox` и `ListBox`.

Теперь мне нужно реализовать, что бы над выделенными элементами в ListBox было выполнено некоторое действие при нажатии на кнопку, которое вернет string, который нужно поместить в `TextBox` на форме.

Кто должен быть ответственен за данную логику?

Сейчас у меня такая штука:

```
   private void StartBtn_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var Config = TaskList.SelectedItems.Cast<TaskInfo>().Select(x => x.Config).ToList();
        ResultTextBox.Text = Merger.Merge(Config);
    }
```

Не уверен, что это соответствует принципам WPF.
Или правильно во вьюхе завезти свойство CurrentResult и его биндить прямо в XAML, а в кнопке просто дергать у вьхи какой-нибудь GetResult ?

Comment: По правилам MVVM код (будь то Model или ViewModel) не как не должны контактировать с View. То есть представьте, что у вас есть dll с вашей логикой, вы написали к ней отдельным приложением интерфейс (View) и привязались к нужным свойствам из dll. Захотели другой дизайн, взяли также, без проблем привязались и используете dll. То есть ваша dll не должна знать, что на окне есть некая кнопка `button1` и ее текст такой то, нет, это не правильно. Мыслите так, будто у вас вовсе нет View и вам надо в коде организовать данные.

Comment: WPF'у все равно, он всё стерпит. Но если вы хотите что-то вроде MVVM, то заведите в VM команду для выполнения действий и текстовое свойство для результата. Команду привяжите к кнопке, а свойство с результатом к TextBox. Всё. А, ну и свойство для выделенных элементов тоже должно быть. Хотя, их можно передать параметром в команду. Пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670865/218063