# Уведомление View об изменении ObservableCollection.Count

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

При добавлении\удалении элемента в коллекции, View не отображает изменения количества элементов. Так же как и при изменении статуса в вложенном объекте.

```
public class GroupComputersVM : BaseVM
{
    public GroupComputersVM(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    private string _Name;
    public string Name { get { return _Name; } set { _Name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); } }

    public string Online { get { return ComputersList.Where(x => x.Status).Count().ToString() + @"/" + ComputersList.Count.ToString(); } }

    private ObservableCollection<ComputerVM> _ComputersList = new ObservableCollection<ComputerVM>();
    public ObservableCollection<ComputerVM> ComputersList { get { return _ComputersList; } set { _ComputersList = value; } }

}
public class ComputerVM : BaseVM
{
    private string _Name;
    public string Name { get { return _Name; } set { _Name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); } }

    private bool _Status;
    public bool Status { get { return _Status; } private set { _Status = value; OnPropertyChanged("Status"); } }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModels : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModels(LogicVM logicVM)
    {
        GroupList = logicVM.GroupList; // поле: public ObservableCollection<GroupComputersVM> GroupList
    }

    public ObservableCollection<GroupComputersVM> GroupList { get; set; }

}
```

View:

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding GroupList}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="40">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="140*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Padding="3,0,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Online}" Padding="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

---

**UPD**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я недопонял, для чего вы создаете свойство зависимотей в главной вью модели? Почему не сохранить свойство просто с приватное поле?

Comment: @tym32167 Я поправил, оно загружается с поля. Я не очень понимаю, вы имейте в виду что можно заменить propdp на простое свойство { get; set; }?

Comment: Ну не на простое свойство, а свойство с уведомлением, когда оно меняется (у вас такие есть уже в коде). Свойство зависимости вам во вьюмодели не нужно совсем

Comment: Во первых, зачем вам для ObservableCollection реализовать INPC? Во вторых, к чему два раза оповещения (`OnPropertyChanged("Status"); OnPropertyChanged("ComputersList");`) ? В третьих, на кой вам конвертор для отображения кол-ва элементов в коллекции, почему просто не написать `{Binding ComputersList.Count}`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ 1,2 это пожалуй следствие попыток заставить работать 3 вопрос. А третье, конвертер отображает количество активных устройств в группе: 0/3, 1/4, 4/4,... как раз эти изменения я не могу отобразить в View

Comment: @i4el0vek Да, не заметил, что там только онлайн. Это делается путем создания дополнительного int свойства, а при изменение Status (в его set) вызывайте метод, который будет обновлять счетчик онлайн, примерно так - `Online = list.Where(x=>x.Status).Count`. Конвертор для этого совсем лишнее и не верное решение.

Comment: @i4el0vek Отвечал недавно [на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/827160/Как-работать-с-событием-selectionchanged-элемента-tabcontrol-wpf/827196#827196), где человеку надо было отслеживать изменения текущей вкладки, там реализация идет как раз на привязку к int свойству и при его изменение вызывается нужное нам действие. Вот вам нужно что то подобное.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я первоначально думал поместить свойство Online, но тогда придется в каждый элемент передавать ссылку на коллекции в которых он содержится, что бы можно было уведомлять их. Или создать одно событие на которое были бы подписаны и группы, и устройства?

Comment: @i4el0vek А почему вообще оно у вас внутри коллекции? Как по мне, это не верный подход. У вас должна быть коллекция и рядом с ней свойства, которые связаны с коллекцией, а отдельной VM у вас идут все свойства, которые связаны с объектом этой коллекции. То, что вы пытаетесь сделать - как по мне не верное размещение элементов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Подготовка

Посмотрев на ваш скриншот я понял, что вам нужно просто вывести группы и кол-во объектов. Ок, давайте разберемся сколько уровней у нас будет:

- Сам список у нас должен содержать группы.

  - "внутренности" группы будут следующими:

    - имя
    - кол-во онлайн (обновляемое)
    - коллекция самих элементов, которая содержит внутренности такого вида:

      - имя
      - статус (обновляемое)

Я сделал пометки "(обновляемое)" у тех свойств, которым надо реализовать INPC. Ну что, давайте приступим к реализации!

### INotifyPropertyChanged

Что это и как использовать?
Ну для начала представим, что на нашей View есть некое текстовое поле в которое мы вводим текст. Как поведет себя программа, если у нас сделана простая привязка к некому свойству Text? В основном из кода вы увидите изменения свойства, но что если наоборот, нам надо изменить значение в коде и что бы оно изменилось в нашей View? Вот в таком случае наш интерфейс не будет знать о том, что свойство было изменено. Для оповещений собственно и используется INPC. Есть как минимум 2 коллекции, которые уже реализуют подобные интерфейсы - это ObservableCollection и BindingList. Для них нет необходимости городить сотню INPC (как у вас).

Хорошо, давайте сделаем базовый класс, который в последующим будем использовать:

```
public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

### ViewModel

ViewModel - это некая прослойка между Model и View в которой реализуется логика для определенного элемента. В нашем случае нужно создать 3 VM (item, group и main).

- **ItemViewModel** - как мы уже определили, в ней должно находится 2 свойства, это имя и статус. Статус у нас может обновится из кода, по этому надо реализовать INPC (наследуемся от ранее созданного класса). Код у нас будет примерно таким:

  ```
  public class ItemViewModel : VM
  {
      public string Name { get; set; }

      private bool status;
      public bool Status
      {
          get => status;
          set
          {
              status = value;
              OnPropertyChanged();
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- **GroupViewModel** - тут также потребуется имя, кол-во онлайн и коллекция. Счетчик онлайн у нас обновляется (реализуем INPC). Что касается коллекции, то нам надо отслеживать статус элементов. Для этого я буду использовать BindingList  и подпишусь на ListChanged событие, которое будет вызывать обновление счетчика онлайн. Код в итоге будет примерно следующим:

  ```
  public class GroupViewModel : VM
  {
      public GroupViewModel()
      {
          List.ListChanged += ListOnListChanged;
      }

      public string Name { get; set; }
      public BindingList<ItemViewModel> List { get; set; } = new BindingList<ItemViewModel>();

      private int online;
      public int Online
      {
          get => online;
          set
          {
              online = value;
              OnPropertyChanged();
          }
      }

      private void ListOnListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
      {
          //if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemChanged)
          UpdateOnline();
      }

      private void UpdateOnline() => Online = List.Count(x => x.Status);
  }
  ```

Видите закомментированную строку? Так мы можем сделать ограничение, при котором будет обновлять статус (к примеру только при изменении, или только при добавление).

- **MainViewModel** - Это уже наша основная VM, которая в свою очередь привязывается. В ней мы создаем основную коллекцию наших групп, ну и для теста заполним ее:

  ```
  public class MainViewModel
  {
      public MainViewModel()
      {
          Groups.Add(new GroupViewModel{Name = "Машины"});
          var machine = Groups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Машины")?.List;
          machine?.Add(new ItemViewModel{Name = "Машина 1", Status = true});
          machine?.Add(new ItemViewModel{Name = "Машина 2", Status = true});
          machine?.Add(new ItemViewModel{Name = "Машина 3", Status = false});
      }

      public ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel> Groups { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<GroupViewModel>();
  }
  ```

Супер, осталось только привязать это все дело, я это сделаю в MainWindow таким способом:

```
private MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; } = new MainViewModel();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = MainViewModel;
}
```

### XAML

В самом XAML я лично нечего мудрить не буду, сделаю просто вывод кол-ва элементов коллекции и саму коллекцию:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Groups.Count, StringFormat=Группы: {0}}"/>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0"/>
                    <TextBlock>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Online, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    <Run Text="/"/>
                    <Run Text="{Binding List.Count, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Вот и все. Вообще по хорошему группировку делать с помощью GroupDescriptions, но в вашем случае без вывода я не знаю, есть ли смысл...

Сам результат:

[image: Result]

Comment: Большое спасибо! Я как раз наткнулся на подобное решение от вас из другого [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/818957/Отлов-события-изменения-observablecollection/818985#818985)