# Не могу понять как забиндить правильно xml

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, mvvm, binding

У меня есть xml файл

```
 <ballast>
  <tank number="32" ID="FPTW" Name="Forepeak" Weight="0,00" SG="1,025" Volume="0,00">
    <volume level="0.00" x="52.00" y="-0.90" z="0.00">0.00</volume>
    <volume level="0.10" x="53.48" y="0.00" z="0.05">0.77</volume>
    <volume level="0,20" x="53,70" y="0,00" z="0,11">1,99</volume>
    <volume level="0,30" x="53,88" y="0,00" z="0,18">3,61</volume>
    <volume level="0,40" x="54,02" y="0,00" z="0,24">5,54</volume>
    <volume level="0,50" x="54,16" y="0,00" z="0,30">7,80</volume>
    <volume level="0,60" x="54,29" y="0,00" z="0,36">10,36</volume>
    <volume level="0,70" x="54,39" y="0,00" z="0,42">13,12</volume>
  </tank>
</ballast>
```

Есть модель

```
public class Model
{
    public static string Path = "XMLFile1.xml";
}
[Serializable]
public class ModelBallast
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public double Sg { get; set; }
    public double Volume { get; set; }
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }
}
```

Есть vm но в ней только `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
class BallastVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Есть view

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Ballast" Height="40" Width="100">
            <DataGrid x:Name="ballastdg" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="3*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Weight" Width="*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="SG" Width="*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Volume" Width="*"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="dcdg" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="3*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Volume" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="X" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Y" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Z" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

И мне надо

1. Binding xml на ballastdg
2. Разрешить юзеру редактировать всё кроме имени с влиянием на другие элементы
   (weight = sg * volume)
3. При volume !=0 показать строку в dcdg с тем показателем volume и соответствующим ему координатам

Comment: Если у вас все по MVVM, то в Model у вас должен быть некий метод, который будет возвращать данные, либо запускать процесс их получения и передавать их с помощью события. В VM у вас должна быть коллекция, которая привязывается к View элементам и метод, который будет из модели забирать данные, заполняя необходимую коллекцию. По поводу пункта 2 - тут в set свойства VM добавьте необходимую логику по подсчету и изменения другого свойства. Пункт 3 не понял немного...

Comment: 3.  Изначально xml биндится в первую дг и у него стартовое значение 0. Если значение поменялось, то строка появляется во второй дг с именем, изменённым значением, и координатами которые относятся к этому значению volume.

Comment: Ну тогда 3-й пункт можно сделать [таким](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/816149/220553) способом.

Comment: а можно какой-то пример по вашим подсказкам?

Comment: а насчёт третьего можно фильтром попробовать но мне надо добавить интерполяцию, то-есть если ввели 11, то программа находит ближайшие значения(10,36 и 13,12) и даёт результат

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала подготовим проект:

1. Я создам две папки `Models` и `ViewModels`.
2. В `ViewModels` создадим новый класс, который будет реализовывать `INotifyPropertyChanged`, назовем его к примеру `BaseVM` и перенесем туда весь ваш код.
3. Также в `ViewModels` создадим еще класс, который укажем как `DataContext`, у меня будет это `MainViewModel`.
4. В `MainWindow.xaml.cs` зададим `DataContext`. После `InitializeComponent();` пишем `DataContext = new MainViewModel();`.

Все, базовую подготовку мы сделали, теперь по порядку:

> Binding xml на ballastdg

Xml по сути можно считать моделью, которая будет иметь методы для загрузки данных и их отдачи в VМ.

1. Создадим в `Models` класс `DataModel` (имена указывайте реальные, у меня это чисто для примера), а также класс `ItemModel`.
2. В классе `ItemModel` я пропишу все необходимые для примера свойства:

   ```
   class ItemModel
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public int Value { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. В `DataModel` сделаем имитацию получения данных, пусть отдает нам некоторые тестовые данные:

   ```
   class DataModel
   {
       public List<ItemModel> GetItems() =>
           new List<ItemModel>
           {
               new ItemModel(1, "Item 1", 33),
               new ItemModel(2, "Item 2", 14),
               new ItemModel(2, "Item 3", 0),
           };
   }
   ```
4. Теперь мы имеем модель, которая готова отдавать нам данные, поработаем с ViewModel. Создадим в папке `ViewModels` класс с названием `ItemViewModel` и реализуем в нем все свойства для привязок и необходимую логику (если есть):

   ```
   class ItemViewModel
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public int Value { get; set; }
   }
   ```
5. В `MainViewModel` подключаем модель, создаем публичное свойство нашей коллекции для привязки и сделаем метод для заполнения ее:

   ```
   class MainViewModel
   {
       private DataModel Data;
       public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }
       public MainViewModel()
       {
           Data = new DataModel();
           Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
           Load();
       }

       public void Load()
       {
           foreach (var item in Data.GetItems())
               Items.Add(new ItemViewModel(item.Id, item.Name, item.Value));
       }
   }
   ```
6. Теперь View. Для удобства в Xaml укажем тип наших данных для дизайнера:

   ```
   d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type vm:MainViewModel}}"
   ```
7. Напишем теперь простенькую разметку:

   ```
   <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
       <DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Название" Width="3*" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Значение" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Value}"/>
       </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
   ```

Все, ваши данные будут успешно отображены в приложении:

[image: Result]

Вам тут останется реализовать сохранение значений при изменении и прочие мелочи.

> Разрешить юзеру редактировать всё кроме имени с влиянием на другие элементы (weight = sg * volume)

**Для запрета изменений** сделайте свойство без `Set`, допустим в моем примере убираем возможность изменить `Id`:

- В `ItemViewModel` переделываем `Id` на `public int Id { get; }`
- В View меняем режим привязки на односторонний `{Binding Id, Mode=OneWay}`.

**Для изменения других значений** объекта в `Set` нужного свойства добавьте логику, но не стоит забывать, что для оповещения интерфейса об изменении свойства, нужен INPC.
Давайте для примера я создам еще одно свойство, которое будет отображать значение умноженное на 2:

- Наследуем `ItemViewModel` от ранее созданного `BaseVM` - `class ItemViewModel : BaseVM`
- Реализуем свойство с оповещением об изменении:

  ```
  private int _customValue;
  public int CustomValue
  {
      get => _customValue;
      set
      {
          _customValue = value;
          RaisePropertyChanged();
      }
  }
  ```
- Изменяем старое свойство, добавляя ему нужную логику:

  ```
  private int _value;
  public int Value
  {
      get => _value;
      set
      {
          _value = value;
          CustomValue = value * 2;
      }
  }
  ```
- Привязываем: `<DataGridTextColumn Header="Значение x2" Width="*" Binding="{Binding CustomValue}"/>`

Смотрим результат:

[image: X2 Result]

> При volume !=0 показать строку в dcdg с тем показателем volume и соответствующим ему координатам

Для этих целей да, лучше использовать фильтрацию. Я покажу на примере `ListCollectionView`.

- В `MainViewModel` создаем новое свойство, к которому будет привязан другой Control и в нем мы будем отображать только отфильтрованные значения:

  ```
  public ListCollectionView FilteredItems { get; set; }
  ```
- Далее в конструкторе `MainViewModel` инициализируем это свойство, задав ему все что нам необходимо:

  ```
  FilteredItems = new ListCollectionView(Items)
  {
      Filter = item => ((ItemViewModel)item).Value != 0,
      IsLiveFiltering = true,
      LiveFilteringProperties =
      {
          nameof (ItemViewModel.Value)
      }
  };
  ```
- По аналогии с вашей View я сделаю снизу отфильтрованные данные:

  ```
  <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Название" Width="3*" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Значение" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Value}"/>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
  ```

Запускаем и смотрим результат:

[image: Sort Result]

Фуф, ну вроде все.
На будущее: пожалуйста, не задавайте несколько вопросов в одном!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88150/discussion-on-answer-by-evgeniyz-------xml).