# Поиск элементов в ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть у нас ListBox, в который через ItemsSource мы загружаем коллекцию объектов. У этих объектов есть свойство Title, и нужно чтобы по этому свойству и происходил поиск в этом листбоксе. Под поиском я имею ввиду такое действие, чтобы в списке показывались только те объекты, у которых свойство Title подходит заданному (пользователь будет вводить в TextBox). Есть какие-нибудь идеи?

Comment: Такое действие называется `фильтр`. Используйте `List<T>().Where(/*лямбда тут для тех, что отобрать */)`

Comment: `мы загружаем коллекцию объектов` загружайте с фильтром по тексту.

Comment: @tym32167 а как мне привязать введенное в текстбокс значение в качестве фильтра?

Comment: через ViewModel конечно

Comment: Я как то писал [данный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/929851/220553) ответ и там реализовывал фильтрацию (в самом низу). Вот примерно тоже самое вам и надо реализовать у себя.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, думаю это то, что мне и нужно. Но только не могли бы подсказать. У вас в примере вы проверяется `Value != 0`, а как можно в качестве условия задать содержимое TextBox'a? Т.е. проверять чтобы `Value == TextBox.Text` (условно)?

Comment: Просто уберите все лишнее, вам достаточно просто инициализировать (`FilteredItems = new ListCollectionView(Items);`). Дальше где и как вам надо, меняйте фильтр на тот, что нужен (что то по типу `FilteredItems.item => ((ItemViewModel)item).Value != 0;`). Все остальное аналогично тому ответу.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ хорошо, благодарю