# Фильтрация источника данных Binding для вывода

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, maui

У меня есть ListView с привязкой на ObservableCollection<Класс> Buses представляющий из себя коллекцию объектов состоящих из нескольких string var представленных как _NameEnded, _NameMarshrut, _TimeArrival. Каждый из них выводится по столбцам внутри Grid и при добавлении нового элемента в коллекцию, создаётся ещё одна строка выводящая внутри всю информацию, это работает как надо.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Buses}">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <ViewCell>
                 <Grid>
                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                         <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
                         <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                         <ColumnDefinition Width="180"></ColumnDefinition>
                         <ColumnDefinition Width="80"></ColumnDefinition>
                     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <Image Grid.Column="0"  HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" Background="Blue" Source="bus_icon.png" />
                     <Label Grid.Column="1" WidthRequest="50" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"  Text="{Binding _NameMarshrut}"></Label>
                     <Label Grid.Column="2" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding _NameEnded}"></Label>
                     <Label Grid.Column="3" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="20" Text="{Binding _TimeArrival}"></Label>
                 </Grid>
             </ViewCell>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Но мне необходимо в моей MVVM модели прописать алгоритм, который позволит выводить только те объекты коллекции Buses, которые по своему полю соответствуют определённым условиям (Например _NameMarshrut == "69"), однако я не очень хорошо понимаю, как работать с ViewModel корректно и на данный момент моя коллекция имеет атрибут read-only, что не позволяет мне, например, выводить через get только те элементы коллекции, которые мне нужны

я пробовал реализовать фильтрацию через get, ожидая возвращения отфильтрованной коллекции, но я понимаю что в данном коде он просто обращается к себе же рекурсивно, кроме того я получаю ошибку
"CS8050 Инициализаторы могут иметь только автоматически реализованные свойства"

```
public string SelectBS; 
public ObservableCollection<ArrivingBusesModel> Buses
    {
         get
         {
             ObservableCollection<ArrivingBusesModel> Filter = new ObservableCollection<ArrivingBusesModel>();
             foreach (var modelBus in Buses)
             {
                 foreach (var Stop in modelBus.marshr.Stops)
                 {
                     if (Stop.Name == selectBS) Filter.Add(modelBus); 

                 }
             }
             return Filter;//(ObservableCollection<ArrivingBusesModel>)buses.Where(p => p.marshr.Stops.Where(x => x.Name == SelectBS).Count() > 0);
         }

     } = new();
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/929851/220553 - Внимание на `ListCollectionView`

Comment: А вот это прям дубликат - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1140841/220553

Comment: ICollectionView.Filter, например это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1131976/373567