# Изменение ItemsSource для ComboBox во время выполнения программы

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть приложение WPF. В окне имеется два ComboBox'а. При изменении значения в первом ComboBox'e мне нужно изменять значение ItemsSource во втором ComboBox'e в рантайме. Пробовал использовать SelectedItem в первом ComboBox'e и через него менять содержимое коллекции, но данный способ не работает. Подскажите, каким образом можно это реализовать ?

Xaml:

```
<ComboBox Margin="255,51,312,338" ItemsSource="{Binding FirstComboBoxCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding FirstComboBoxSelectedItem}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox Margin="255,99,312,290" ItemsSource="{Binding SecondComboBoxCollection}" IsEnabled="{Binding SecondComboBoxIsEnabled}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    readonly ApplicationContext db;
    public ObservableCollection<string> FirstComboBoxCollection { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> SecondComboBoxCollection { get; set; }


    public MainViewModel()
    {
        db = new ApplicationContext();
        FirstComboBoxCollection = CollectionResources.FirstComboBox;

    }

    private string firstComboBoxSelectedItem;
    public string FirstComboBoxSelectedItem
    {
        get { return firstComboBoxSelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            firstComboBoxSelectedItem = value;
            if(firstComboBoxSelectedItem == CollectionResources.games)
            {
                SecondComboBoxCollection = CollectionResources.SecondComboBoxGames;
                SecondComboBoxIsEnabled = true;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstComboBoxSelectedItem");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

Comment: [Это?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/816149/220553)

Comment: Не совсем, в вашем примере массив инициализирован и в ходе выполнения программы не изменяется. Мне же нужно, чтобы при изменении значения первого комбобокса, коллекция SecondComboBoxCollection, которая является ItemsSource для второго  комбобокса, заполнялась новыми значениями прямо во время выполнения программы..

Comment: Ну тогда это как то странно, но да ладно. Если вы пишете `= new ...`, то наверно надо оповестить UI о том, что свойство изменилось, верно? Где тогда у вас INPC  для `SecondComboBoxCollection `?

Comment: Как именно мне стоит реализовать INPC для коллекции? По аналогии с **FirstComboBoxSelectedItem** или необходимо использовать **ICollectionView** ?

Comment: А какая разница для чего вы делаете INPC? У вас привязка идет не к типу же, а к свойству, вот для свойства и реализуйте.

Comment: Благодарю за совет, теперь работает корректно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы `ComboBox` узнавал о том, что коллекция сменилась на другую, нужно вызывать `OnPropertyChanged()` при изменении коллекции.

```csharp
private ObservableCollection<string> _firstComboBoxCollection;
private ObservableCollection<string> _secondComboBoxCollection;
public ObservableCollection<string> SecondComboBoxCollection 
{ 
    get => _secondComboBoxCollection;
    set 
    {
        _secondComboBoxCollection = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
public ObservableCollection<string> FirstComboBoxCollection
{
    get => _firstComboBoxCollection;
    set
    {
        _firstComboBoxCollection = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Фактически, вам не нужно изменять `ItemsSource`, а только само свойство `SecondComboBoxCollection`, на которое привязан `Binding`. Собственно, что вы и делаете, просто `ComboBox` в вашем случае об этом не узнаёт.