# Как при изменении выбранного элемента ListBox изменять содержимое ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

Столкнулся с трудностью.
Создаю приложение с MVVM.
Есть ListBox, 2 TextBox-а и Combobox. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при изменении выбранного элемента изменялись содержимые контролов. Изменить содержимое TextBox-ов получается, но как изменять заполнение ComboBox-а?
Нужно, чтобы при выборе First ComboBox содержал значения (1, 2, 3), при Second - (10, 20, 30), при Third - (100, 200, 300)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Модель:

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int x, y, z;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<int> Z_values = new List<int>();

    public int X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set
        {
            x = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("X");
        }
    }
    public int Y
    {
        get { return y; }
        set
        {
            y = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Y");
        }
    }
    public int Z
    {
        get { return z; }
        set
        {
            z = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Z");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Model current;

    public ObservableCollection<Model> Models { get; set; }

    public Model Current
    {
        get { return current; }
        set
        {
            current = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Current");
        }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Models = new ObservableCollection<Model>
        {
            new Model{Name="First", X=1, Y=1, Z_values={ 1, 2, 3} },
            new Model{Name="Second", X=2, Y=2, Z_values={ 10, 20, 30}},
            new Model{Name="Third", X=3, Y=3, Z_values={ 100, 200, 300}}
        };
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox x:Name="list1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Models}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="5">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBox x:Name="X" Text="{Binding Models/X, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Y" Text="{Binding Models/Y, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="Z" Height="20" ItemsSource="{Binding Models/Z_values}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [При помощи каких средств можно сделать отображение сообщений как в outlook?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/816132/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-outlook)

Comment: Нужно, чтобы содержимое комбобокса зависело от выбранной строки листбокса. То есть если мы выбираем ряд First, содержимое комбобокса - (1, 2, 3), если Second - (10, 20, 30), если Third - (100, 200, 300)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сложно было понять, что нужно, хотя-бы потому, что у вас разные числа в коде и в вопросе. Но рассмотрите такой вариант, и вместо свойства `Current` можно попробовать использовать `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`.

```xaml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox x:Name="list1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Models}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="5">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBox x:Name="X" Text="{Binding Models/X, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Y" Text="{Binding Models/Y, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="Z" Height="20" ItemsSource="{Binding Models}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Z}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

При условии, что вы эту уже переопределяете `ItemTemplate` у `ListBox`, я не понял, почему вы не сделали то же самое `ComboBox`.

Кстати, ради развлечения, попробуйте комбобоксу тоже задать `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` и посмотрите, что будет. :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но вопрос был немного в другом. Нужно, чтобы содержимое комбобокса зависело от выбранной строки листбокса. То есть если мы выбираем ряд First, содержимое комбобокса - (1, 2, 3), если Second - (10, 20, 30), если Third - (100, 200, 300)

Comment: @Vladislav а теперь посмотрите в свой код, в котором я не нашел 10, 20 и 30.

Comment: Собственно, в том и проблема. Я не знаю, где и как определить эти нужные 10, 20, 30 и др., чтобы иметь возможность использовать их в ComboBox. Нужно добавить еще один ObservableCollection и привязать к нему ComboBox? Но в таком случае нужно будет как-то менять ItemSourse и не будет привязки к ListBox

Comment: @Vladislav определите их как список, комбобокс привязывается к списку. Внесите этот список как свойство в свой класс с данными. `ObservableCollection` нужно использовать там, где есть динамическое изменение списка, в противном случае можно использовать хоть `List`.

Comment: В класс Model добавил public List<int> Z_values = new List<int>(); Во WievModel объявление нового элемента теперь выглядит так: new Model{Name="First", X=1, Y=1, Z_values={ 1, 2, 3} }, у комбомокса ItemsSource="{Binding Models/Z_values}, но теперь он снова пустой

Comment: @Vladislav Привязка идет к публичным свойствам, `public List<int> Z_values = new List<int>();` похоже на свойство?

Comment: Разобрался, большое спасибо