# Отловить событие нажатия пользователя на строку

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, datagridview

в WPF есть форма, хочу чтобы при нажатии пользователем в datagrid на заголовок строки - в коде получался ID в строке для дальнейшего редактирование, не подскажете каким событием это можно реализовать, т.е. какое событие DataGridView за это отвечает?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас должны быть привязки, при помощи которых отделяете данные от UI. Если у вас так, то просто привяжите `SelectedItem` к нужному свойству. Если ваша задача заполнить поля ниже, при клике на объект, то можно вообще без C# кода это сделать, примерно [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/816149/220553), ну а далье просто `Редактировать` - это команда, которая берет `SelectedItem` и записывает его, например в базу. Вот и вся ваша программа.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, не очень понимаю как это можно реализовать

Comment: [Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0)

Comment: Что именно? Привязки? `<... SelectedItem = "{Binding MySelectedItem}">`, где `MySelectedItem` это свойство с типом ваших данных в классе, который задан как `DataContext` контролу или окну (`public MySuperClass { public MyDataClass MySelectedItem {get; set;} }` `MainWindow(){ DataContext = new MySuperClass(); }`). Ну а про отображение выделенного объекта в другом контроле я дал вам подробный пример выше.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1139388/373567