# WPF как редактировать listbox через textbox

Tags: wpf, mvvm, textbox, listbox

Я хочу, чтобы выделенный элемент listbox'a редактировался в x = textbox, а потом снова добавлялся в listbox.
Как это можно сделать?

```
<TextBox Name="tb_x" Text="{Binding ElementName=x, Path=SelectedValue}"/>
<ListBox Name="x" ItemsSource="{Binding Args_x}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Args_x, XPath=tb_x}" Width="55"/>
```

[image: -]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [При помощи каких средств можно сделать отображение сообщений как в outlook?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/816132/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-outlook)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ , здесь только отображение элементов в textblock. это и я могу. а мне нужно вернуть обратно измененный.

Comment: И какая разница, отображение или редактирование? Если у вас привязка успешно отработала в режиме TwoWay, то если вы привяжете например к `TextBox`, то при редактирование там текста изменения будут везде, где используется это свойство.