# SQlite MVVM Вывести в ComboBox значения таблицы

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, mvvm

В рамках MVVM разрабатываю приложение для базы данных SQlite.
База состоит из таблиц:
Orders(Id(Первичный ключ), Number, NameOfItem, Employee(ссылка на сотрудника из таблицы Staff))
Staff(Id(Первичный ключ), LastName, Name, MiddleName, DateofBirth, Gender, Unit)

На форме для добавления заказа(OrderWindow) необходимо сделать Combobox "Сотрудник" и вывести в него данные из таблицы Staff(для примера что угодно, хоть Id, хоть Name), чтобы выбранный элемент, в последствии, записывался в таблицу Order.
Гуглил этот вопрос, но варианты решений рушат MVVM...

На данный момент есть один вариант, как вывести данные(фамилию) из таблицы Staff в comboBox: `DataContext = new ViewModel();` и `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Staffs}" DisplayMemberPath="LastName"/>` для View OrderWindow, но тогда не выводятся значения выбранного элемента таблицы Order, а если же убрать `DataContext = new ViewModel();` и оставить
`
public Order Order { get; private set; }

```
    public OrderWindow(Order p)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Order = p;
        DataContext = Order;
        //DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }`
```

то данные из таблицы Order выводятся, но comboBox не заполняется элементами из Staff.

Может знает кто вариант решения проблемы? Так как основной код строился на основе статьи из Метанита (https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.1.php)

ViewModel

{
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
ApplicationContext db;
RelayCommand addCommand;
RelayCommand editCommand;
IEnumerable orders;
RelayCommand addCommandStaff;
RelayCommand editCommandStaff;
IEnumerable staffs;

```
        public IEnumerable<Order> Orders
        {
            get { return orders; }
            set
            {
                orders = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Orders");
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Staff> Staffs
        {
            get { return staffs; }
            set
            {
                staffs = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Staffs");
            }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            db = new ApplicationContext();
            db.Orders.Load();
            Orders = db.Orders.Local.ToBindingList();
            db.Staffs.Load();
            Staffs = db.Staffs.Local.ToBindingList();
            
        }

        public RelayCommand AddCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return addCommand ??
                  (addCommand = new RelayCommand((o) =>
                  {
                      OrderWindow orderWindow = new OrderWindow(new Order());
                      if (orderWindow.ShowDialog() == true)
                      {
                          Order order = orderWindow.Order;
                          db.Orders.Add(order);
                          db.SaveChanges();
                      }
                  }));
            }
        }      

        public RelayCommand EditCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return editCommand ??
                  (editCommand = new RelayCommand((selectedItem) =>
                  {
                      if (selectedItem == null) return;
                      Order order = selectedItem as Order;
                      
                      Order vm = new Order()
                      {
                          Id = order.Id,
                          Number = order.Number,
                          NameOfItem = order.NameOfItem,
                          Employee = order.Employee
                      };

                      OrderWindow orderWindow = new OrderWindow(vm);


                      if (orderWindow.ShowDialog() == true)
                      {
                          order = db.Orders.Find(orderWindow.Order.Id);
                          if (order != null)
                          {
                              order.Number = orderWindow.Order.Number;
                              order.NameOfItem = orderWindow.Order.NameOfItem;
                              order.Employee = orderWindow.Order.Employee;
                              db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
                              db.SaveChanges();
                          }
                      }
                  }));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
}
```

OrderWindow.cs

```
public partial class OrderWindow : Window
    {
        public Order Order { get; private set; }
        public Staff Staff1 { get; private set; }

        public OrderWindow(Order p)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Order = p;
            DataContext = Order;
            
            //DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }
```

Класс Order

```
public class Order : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private int number;
        private string nameofitem;
        private string employee;

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int Number
        {
            get { return number; }
            set
            {
                number = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Number");
            }
        }

        public string NameOfItem
        {
            get { return nameofitem; }
            set
            {
                nameofitem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("NameOfItem");
            }
        }
        public string Employee
        {
            get { return employee; }
            set
            {
                employee = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Employee");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
```

Класс Staff

```
public class Staff : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string lastname;
        private string name;
        private string middlename;
        private DateTime dateofbirth;
        public enum gender
        {
            male = 1,
            female = 2,
        };
        private string unit;

        public int Id { get; set; }

        

        public string LastName
        {
            get { return lastname; }
            set
            {
                lastname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        public string MiddleName
        {
            get { return middlename; }
            set
            {
                middlename = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MiddleName");
            }
        }

        public DateTime DateOfBirth
        {
            get { return dateofbirth; }
            set
            {
                dateofbirth = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DateOfBirth");
            }
        }

        private gender _gender;
        public gender Gender
        {
            get { return _gender; }
            set
            {
                _gender = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Gender");
            }
        }

        public string Unit
        {
            get { return unit; }
            set
            {
                unit = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Unit");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
```

OrderWindow.XAML

```
</Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="110" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Номер" />
        <TextBlock Text="Название товара" Grid.Row="1" />
        <TextBlock Text="Сотрудник" Grid.Row="2" />
        <TextBlock Text="Тест" Grid.Row="3" />

        <TextBox Text="{Binding Number}" Grid.Column="1" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding NameOfItem}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Employee}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Staffs}" DisplayMemberPath="LastName"     Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" />
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1">
            <Button IsDefault="True" Click="Accept_Click" MinWidth="60" Margin="5">OK</Button>
            <Button IsCancel="True" MinWidth="60" Margin="5">Отмена</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: тяжело понять, что вы делаете и в чем у вас проблема. Можете привести [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: `но тогда не выводятся значения выбранного элемента таблицы Order` - ну, наверно потому, что источник данных, который вы задаете как `DataContext` (`ViewModel`), не содержит в себе `Order` (и его данные). Посмотрите еще раз, что вы делаете и как, не знаю, нарисуйте себе на листочке связи, что и где находится. Сейчас я думаю, что вы просто запутались.

Comment: @tym32167 Добавил в исходное сообщение

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Не исключено, но в том и дело, что связи отрисовал, как понял, и вроде как всё правильно, но... MVVM только изучаю, поэтому трудности...

Comment: Xaml забыли, если говорите, что не показывает, то показывайте как привязываете и что. P.S. Вы же программист, не дублируйте код, зачем вам везде реализация INPC?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Добавил. Про INPC не учёл, спасибо)

Comment: Ну и что вы там отрисовывали и проверяли? `Binding Staffs` - где свойство `Staffs` в `Order`? Почему оно должно отобразить то, чего нет? Ну и обратное, допустим `Binding Employee`, где свойство `Employee` в `ViewModel`? Вы уж определитесь, какие данные и как хотите отобразить. Также я заметил `Click="Accept_Click"` - по правилам MVVM это плохо, используйте команды.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Employee, NameOfItem и Number из Order, модель есть, во вью модели тоже есть обработка этого. А как можно объявить Staffs в Order? Я просто только недавно начал изучать всё это дело... Accept_Click в качестве кнопки OK, не знал, что это неправильно, учту)

Comment: `Staffs в Order` - а какая у них связь? Вот допустим, есть "сотрудники", а также есть один заказ. Вы сейчас хотите в один заказ запихнуть список сотрудников, вопрос - зачем? Почему заказ знает про сотрудников? `во вью модели тоже есть обработка этого` - где в `ViewModel` (классе), эти свойства? Я вижу, например `IEnumerable<Order> Orders` - это как я понял список заказов, выводите его, далее берите то, что выбрано в отдельное свойство (или используйте [IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/816149/220553)), а от него уже привязывайтесь (прим: `{Binding Prop.Number}`)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Запихнуть одно в другое для окна добавления или редактирования заказа, чтобы выбирать сотрудника из списка и вносить его в БД для таблицы Order. Ох, попробую) Спасибо большое!

Comment: `Запихнуть одно в другое для окна добавления или редактирования заказа` - но тем самым вы нарушаете кучу других правил программирования, например S из SOLID, которое говорит о единой ответственности ваших сущностей. Ваш класс заказа должен содержать лишь ссылку на сотрудника (`Staff`), не сам список всех сотрудников. А вот окно редактирования, должно уже эти данные подгружать из разных мест и выводить пользователю для выбора. Как я уже говорил выше, просто сделайте классы, которые будут отвечать за что-то одно и дальше хоть на листочке их свяжите друг с другом, посмотрите как лучше делать.