# Как показать сообщение выбраное в listbox используя IMAP

Tags: wpf, imap

Есть функция которая выводит все сообщения из INBOX в listbox(lbPreview)

`lbPreview` у меня только для вывода превью сообщения

```
        private Task LoadFull()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new ImapClient())
                {
                    using (var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource())
                    {
                        client.Connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, true, cancel.Token);
                        client.Authenticate("mymail@gmail.com", "mypassword", cancel.Token);
                        // get message from INBOX
                        var inbox = client.Inbox;
                        inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly, cancel.Token);

                        // show in toolbox
                        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            txtCountMessage.Text = inbox.Count.ToString();
                        }));

                        // for all message
                        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++)
                            {
                                var message = inbox.GetMessage(i, cancel.Token);
                                lbPreviewMail.Items.Add(message.Subject);
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        });
    }
```

Так же у меня есть ещё один listbox

[image: Как это все выглядит]

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на lbPreview в lbAllMessage вывести всё сообщение?!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/816149/220553

Comment: не коректно к моему вопросу(

Comment: Из-за того, что вы пренебрегли всеми современными технологиями и правилами проектирования, по типу хотя бы базовых привязок? Ну, может быть. Делайте тогда дальше костыли в виде события выбора, по которому будет загружена информация куда вам надо. Сейчас, источником ваших данных являются контролы (`ListBox` и др.), что очень плохо, ибо так вы сами себя связываете, оставляя минимальное место для дальнейших маневров. По-хорошему, все сообщения, должны быть в виде отдельных классов, а еще лучше, должны быть привязаны к UI, а не заданы напрямую. И да, не забывайте ставить все метки вопросу (c#)!

Comment: Так ведь нету разницы!
У меня вопрос был таков: `как показать выбраное сообщение`

Comment: Как это нет разницы? Она огромная, начиная банальным уменьшением кода (ведь если вы привязываете, то многое за вас делает сам WPF), и заканчивая той же производительностью (ведь если у вас грамотно спроектирован проект, то вы и ресурсов потребляете меньше, к примеру сейчас вы постоянно дергаете UI, ибо все данные в нем, а должны быть в простом классе). Это я еще не говорю про удобность, ведь если в вашем коде надо будет что-то изменить/добавить, то это означает переписывание всего кода. На ваш вопрос я уже сказал, что делать `Делайте тогда дальше костыли в виде события выбора`.

Answer (score 0):

Решил свою проблему с помощью linq

```
            using (var client = new ImapClient())
        {
            using (var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource())
            {

                client.Connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, true, cancel.Token);

                // If you want to disable an authentication mechanism,
                // you can do so by removing the mechanism like this:
                client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH");

                client.Authenticate("chorrnyinc@gmail.com", "epvytbgottgvwexh", cancel.Token);

                // The Inbox folder is always available...
                var inbox = client.Inbox;
                inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly, cancel.Token);
                // let's try searching for some messages...
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    var query = SearchQuery.DeliveredAfter(DateTime.Parse("2021-01-01"))
                    .And(SearchQuery.SubjectContains(tbSearching.Text)
                    .And(SearchQuery.Seen));

                    foreach (var uid in inbox.Search(query, cancel.Token))
                    {
                        var message = inbox.GetMessage(uid, cancel.Token);
                        lbPreviewMail.Items.Add(message.Subject);
                    }
                }));
            }
        }
```