# Обработчик события Click гиперссылки не видит фрейм

Tags: c#, wpf, click, navigation, frame

Сделал на странице в WPF разбивку на несколько отдельных фреймов со страницами. Задача сделать по фрейму с оглавлением слева переход на разные страницы с текстом справа- уже в другом фрейме. Решил реализовать через  и её параметр click с обработчиком событий в C#, но при попытке прописать в C# навигацию по страницам в другом фрейме компилятор не видит этого фрейма.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код, задающий два фрейма:

```
<Frame Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="listframe"></Frame>
    <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="soderzhaniyeframe"></Frame>
```

Код, задающий гиперссылки и создающий обработчик события:

```
<Paragraph>
                1.<Hyperlink x:Name="Theme1hyper" Click="Theme1hyper_Click"> Первая тема</Hyperlink>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>
                <Hyperlink x:Name="Theme1_1pdhyper" Click="Theme1_1pdhyper_Click">1 Подтема</Hyperlink>
            </Paragraph>
```

Код события click на C#, который я пытаюсь применить, но компилятор не видит soderzhaniyeframe:

```
  private void Theme1hyper_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        soderzhaniyeframe.navigation(new soderzhanie_page()); 

    }
```

Comment: А вам принципиально фреймы нужны?

Comment: Если есть иное решение, которое будет работать по аналогии- готов применить и его.

Comment: У Ваших под тем могут быть еще под темы и так далее?

Comment: Под темы у под тем не не планируются

Comment: Вы фреймы используете чтобы правая часть (там где "описание" главы) имела возможность листать? Как книга в зависимости от главы меняет количество/контент страниц в правой части.

Comment: Да, каждая часть- самостоятельное окно, которое можно листать и менять при необходимости

Comment: А оглавление меняется при нажатии на кнопки сверху (оглавление, глоссарий итд..)? Или оглавление статично?

Comment: Дополните вопрос новой информацией о том, что вы хотите сделать, а что не получается. Сейчас не особо понятно в чем заключается проблема. Переформулируйте текст как минимум.

Comment: Я хочу сделать чтобы при нажатии на гиперссылку в одном фрейме в другом фрейме открылась нужная страница. Всё.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала стоит Вам прочитать про `Binding` в `Wpf`. Так как `Wpf` был нацелен непосредственно на `MVVM`, то и про него стоило бы прочитать и использовать данный подход. Работать с обработчиками событий у контролов неудобно, для этого и существует привязка (она же `Binding`)

Материала достаточно на YouTube (Павел Шмачилин, у него там часовые видео по WPF), есть Метанит, да и у Майкрософта есть [хорошие примеры](https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples)

Касаемо Вашей задачи, для начала создадим класс `BaseViewModel` и реализуем в ней `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Метод `SetProperty` позволит нам перенести часто используемый код в отдельный метод.

Теперь `BaseViewModel`.

```
class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

    public void SetProperty<T>(ref T store, T value, [CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        if(store.Equals(value))
           return;

        store = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(prop);
    }
}
```

Теперь нам нужен класс модели которая будет содержать в себе данные. Назовем её `Theme`, поскольку нам нужен список тем и подтем. В этом методе переопределю `ToString()` который будет возвращать `Title` (Это не самое удачное решение, потому что для вывода `ToString()` не используется, но мы опустим этот момент)

```
public class Theme
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Title;
    }
}
```

Создадим `ThemeViewModel` которую будем привязывать ко всему окну.

```
class ThemeViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string _content;
    private string _title;

    //Эти свойства будем привязывать к конкретным элементам окна
    public string Title { get => _title; set => SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
    public string ThemeContent { get => _content; set => SetProperty(ref _content, value); }
    public ObservableCollection<Theme> Themes { get; set; }

    public ThemeViewModel()
    {
        InitThemes();
    }

    private void InitThemes()
    {
        //Это можно получить из БД к примеру, но я заполню вручную. 
        Themes = new ObservableCollection<Theme>();

        Theme theme = new Theme
        {
            Title = "Title 1",
            Content = "Content 1",
        };
        Theme theme2 = new Theme
        {
            Title = "Title 2",
            Content = "Content 2"
        };

        Themes.Add(theme);
        Themes.Add(theme2);
    }
}
```

Теперь окно `xaml`. Заметьте, что я добавил `SelectionChanged` у `ListBox`.

```
<Window x:Class="wpftest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:wpftest.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="700">

    <!-- Обозначим контекст данных, из этого класса будут браться данные -->
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:ThemeViewModel></vm:ThemeViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
         <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="45"></RowDefinition>
          <RowDefinition Height="200"></RowDefinition>
          <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
        <ListBox x:Name="listBoxThemes" ItemsSource="{Binding Themes}" 
                SelectionChanged="listboxThemes_SelectionChanged">
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <ScrollViewer>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ThemeContent}" FontSize="15" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                </TextBlock>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Внутри `MainWindow.cs`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void listboxThemes_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Приводим текущий контекст данных к нашей ThemeViewModel и задаем свойство ThemeContent из SelectedItem нашего листбокса. Такое возможно, поскольку к листбоксу мы привязали ObservableCollection<Theme>
        (this.DataContext as ThemeViewModel).ThemeContent = (listBoxThemes.SelectedItem as Theme).Content;
    }
}
```

Теперь запустим и вот что получим:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если уж делаете по правилам MVVM, то не нарушайте их. В MVVM слой UI (View) должен быть максимально отвязан от приложения и не зависеть от данных, он должен лишь привязаться, не более. Другими словами, в MVVM не должно быть `SelectionChanged="listboxThemes_SelectionChanged`. Хотите по правилам, так привяжите выделенный объект и `TextBlock` к одному свойству, будет вам по правилам. А вообще, представленный вами вариант делается очень просто на самом [XAML](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/816149/220553). Ну и последнее, как это отвечает на поставленный вопрос? Где тут гиперссылки, параграфы?