# Как выводить страницу с данными в зависимости от выбранного элемента в TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonia

По сути TreeView должен работать как TabControl, только данные (включая контролы, не только текст) должны выводиться в другой части окна. Само окно разбито на несколько частей через DockPanel, слева у меня TreeView, который биндится к списку нодов, но не понимаю, как сделать биндинг из другой панели и использовать текущий нод как ключ.

```
<DockPanel>
    
    <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <TextBlock Text="Top"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
    
    <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <TextBlock Text="Bottom"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
    
    <!-- Сам TreeView -->
    <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Left" MinWidth="160">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Menu"/>
            <TreeView Items="{Binding Menu}">
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <TreeDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </TreeDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
    
    <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Right"  MinWidth="160">
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*" RowDefinitions="*,*">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Table 1"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Table 2"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
    
    <!-- Здесь должны быть страницы -->
    <Border>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <TextBlock Text="Center"/>
        </ScrollViewer> 
    </Border>
    
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/816149/220553

Comment: Спасибо, то, что нужно

Comment: @EvgeniyZ у меня подобная проблема, но это решение для WPF, а авалонии оно не работает. У автора тоже авалония указана

Comment: Не хочу подобный вопрос задавать, а то закроют как дубляж

Comment: @YD359 Ну что я могу сказать, страдайте, раз используете фиг пойми что (до сих пор не пойму смысл использовать эту авалонию..). Пишите авторам фреймворка, пусть расскажут что именно такое изменили в стандартных функциях WPF, что не работает. А по поводу этого вопроса, тут стоит метка wpf, что означает "решения под WPF уместны".