# Работа с вложеними списками WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть 2 класса, первый Job хранит в себе список второго JobTitle

Задача в том чтобы при нажатии на элемент списка Job в втором списке выводилось содержимое его подсписка JobTitle.

Как в коде это реализовать не очень понимаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**XAML**

```
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="Jobs" Grid.Column="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path = Jobs}">
            <DataGrid.Columns >
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = Name}" Header="Job" Width="200*"  IsReadOnly="False"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <DataGrid x:Name="dgJobTitle" Grid.Column="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path = Jobs}">
            <DataGrid.Columns >
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="JobTitle" Width="200*" IsReadOnly="False"  Binding="{Binding Path = _Jobs}">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

**ViewModel**

```
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
        
        private List<Job> _jobs;
        public List<Job> Jobs
        {
            get { return _jobs; }
            set
            {
                _jobs = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Jobs");
            }
        }
        public MainViewModel() 
        {
 
            Jobs = new List<Job>();
            
        }
    }
```

**Классы**

```
class Job : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
       private string name;
        
    }
    
internal class JobTitle : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
 
 
        string name; 
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        
        public List<Item> items;
    }
```

Comment: ComboBox добавьте в ваше View и туда забиндите нужный список из JobTitle. В итоге при изменении выбранного элемента Job будет и меняться ComboBox.Items

Comment: нет мне не подходит  ComboBox так как в планах возможность редактировать его тоже прикреплю изображение окна

Comment: У Combobox есть свойство `IsEditable`, указываете `IsEditable = True` и никаких проблем.

Comment: Синхронизация вам [в помощь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/816149/220553).

Comment: Спасибо но все же я не понимаю как мне работать с коллекции внутри коллекции можно пример пожалуйста ?

Comment: Эм, там прям полноценный код с подробным описанием что да как делать. Не ленитесь!

Comment: Я не ленюсь. просто я действительно не могу понять как написать в XAML **Binding**  коллекции которая в другой коллекции. Хоть может это и полная глупость с моей стороны. @EvgeniyZ

Comment: А как еще назвать, если вы не видите решения по ссылке выше? Ок, давайте тыкну носом: Читаем с `Все элементы мы привязываем как обычно, но только с указанием еще имени нашей коллекции`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо вам за помощь, но этот абзац я читал тоже внимательно, я просто совершил небольшую ошибку которую не мог найти. Ваш ответ очень помог.

Comment: Если совершаете ошибку, то и давайте нам эту ошибку, показывайте код как пробовали, а то "не понимаю". Вот встаньте, например на мое место, вы даете человеку ссылку, где черным по белому написано решение, прям дословно и по пунктам разбирается, а в ответ вы видите "Не понимаю, дайте мне код". Как вы на это отреагируете? Думаю, как и я, подумаете, что человек лениться даже прочитать то, что ему дают, а хочет лишь готовое, чтоб решили все за него. Поэтому на будущее не "не понимаю", а конкретно пишите, что и как делали, и что не получается.

Comment: да собственно не правильно прописал  Binding второй колонки  
 ` <DataGrid x:Name="dgJobTitle"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path = Jobs}" >
<DataGridTextColumn Header="JobTitle"  Binding="{Binding Path = JobsTitle/Name}">` 
от этого были вылеты. заменил на:
`ItemsSource="{Binding Path = Jobs/JobsTitle}"
Binding="{Binding Path = Name}`