# Как сделать привязку редактирования в ListView

Tags: c#, listview, binding, maui

Я начал изучать .Net MAUI. Делаю Note App под windows. Так же с применением MVVM паттерна, его так же использую впервые. Проблема заключается что я не знаю как реализовать Редактирование ячейки в ListView. Я добавляю элемент в ListView, могу нажать на него и получить информацию, но как Отредактировать ячейки не знаю.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}" ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type model:Note}">
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding Title}" Detail="{Binding Detail}" TextColor="#9a26ff"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Вот привязка к ListView

```
internal partial class NotesViewModel : ObservableObject 
    {
       

        [ObservableProperty]
        private ObservableCollection<Note> notes = new();

        [ObservableProperty]
        private Note note = new();

        [RelayCommand]
        private void Save(Note? note)
        {
            if (note is null)
            {
                Notes.Add(Note);
                Note = new();
                
            }
            else
            {
                note = new Note();
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

[image: App]

Comment: Ну, наверно заменить не редактируемый `TextCell` на что-то, что это позволяет, например, `TextBox`? И да `ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped"` - это нарушение MVVM, ибо View слой **не должен знать** про другие слои, про данные, а у вас прям в классе окна вдруг событие в котором вы обрабатываете данные. В MVVM все основывается на привязках, включая все события, которые заменяются командами (`ICommand`). Конкретно в вашем случае, там достаточно простого `ListView SelectedItem="{Binding ...}"` (ну или чет аналогичное).

Comment: Я знал что ```ItemTapped``` это нарушение, но я просто не знал чем заменить, спасибо. ```TextCell``` Мне подходит. При нажатии на кнопку сохранения в ```ListView``` добавляется новый ```TextCell``` Для просмотра полной его информации нужно на него нажать и его информация отобразиться в соответствующих полях (Title в Title, Detail в Detail) за тем после редактирования и нажатия кнопки сохранения нужно что бы этот ```TextCell``` редактировался, а не создавался новый. В вопросе приложу скрин приложения

Comment: Для начала, зачем вам вообще кнопка "Save", когда вы можете в реал тайме редактировать выделенное, привязав к выделенному объекту, ну или [синхронизация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/816149/220553). Ну а добавление... Яб на вашем месте сделал 2 текстовых свойства "текст" и "заголовок", привязал к ним поля, которые для редактирования, ну а дальше, при выделении элемента делал бы условно `Title = selectedItem.Title;` и аналогично так для всех полей, ну а по кнопке "сохранить" делал обратное `selectedItem.Title = Title;` или добавление нового на основе этих данных.

Comment: Я попробовал что то такое 
        ```[RelayCommand]
        public void ListView_ItemTapped()
        {
            
        }```
Но не знаю что писать в методе. Как обратиться к тому самому "Selected Item". Свойства "Title" и "Detail" у меня есть они уже в ```{Binding}```. Соответственно мне нужно что бы при выделении элемента данные из него отправлялись в эти самые "Title" и "Detail" и Изменялись без нажатия кнопки, это хорошая идея, я в теории понимаю как это, но на практике ничего сварганить не могу(

Comment: `ItemTapped` - это событие (view часть), которая вам не нужна. Повторю `SelectedItem` привязываете его к свойству в ViewModel и на его основе делаете нужную логику. Ну а так, как вы используете Community Toolkit для реализации INPC, то вы можете написать [метод](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty#running-code-upon-changes), который будет вызываться в момент изменения свойства, например `public partial OnMySuperProperyChanged(MySuperClass newValue) { //Делаем что-то }`

Comment: То есть, у вас в VM должно быть `[ObservableProperty] private Note _selectedNote; public partial void OnSelectedNodeChanged(Note? newValue){ // ... }` Ну а в XAML `<ListView SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNode}">`, все, при клике должен вызываться метод, а в свойстве `SelectedNode` будет то, что выбрано. Дальше уже делаете остальную логику, например, как сказал ранее `Title = SelectedNode.Title;`, где `Title` это привязанное свойство к простому `TextBox`.

Comment: Подскажите где у меня должна быть реализация ```partial``` метода. 
p.s (У меня ошибка: Отсутствует определяющее объявление для реализующего объявления разделяемого метода...)

Comment: Вот чтоб таких вопросов не было, я вам советую отказаться от Community Toolkit и реализовать команды и INPC самостоятельно. Ну а так, я вам выше вроде все объяснил где и что должно быть, даже ссылку на документацию дал, не представляю с чего такой вопрос и как еще на него можно ответить.

Comment: У меня ещё явно недостаточно знаний. Спасибо за помощь в моём вопросе! И не знаете ли где есть хороший материал по "MVVM" и Maui. Спасибо

Comment: MAUI это продвижение WPF, за исключением некоторых аспектов, можете искать любую информацию по WPF и она в 99% будет подходить под MAUI, поймете ее, там уже дотянете знания самого MAUI. Что касательно "хороший материал" - у зарубежных коллег) Очень сильно советую смотреть зарубежные сайты, ютуб каналы, и прочее, Ру сегмент в этом плане посоветует много мусорного, увы. Что конкретно... Мне в свое время очень сильно помогли видео AngelSix, там прям подробнейшие видео по созданию проекта, всякие фишки языка - 
Nick Chapsas, еще James Montemagno полезности дает, ну а остальное - документация)