# Как отобразить данные в Sub UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf

**Вопрос:** Как отобразить данные в **IndexesView**?
**IndexesView** отображается в **MainWindow**
Как отобразить **IndexesView** в **ManagerIndexesView**?
Т.е. как и где правильно прописать биндинг к **IndexesView**?

https://github.com/jhon65496/DataDisplayWpfApp1

При отладке получаю сообщение в VS:

```cs
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'IndexesViewModel2' property not found on 'object' ''ManagerIndexesViewModel' (HashCode=22385437)'. 

BindingExpression:Path=IndexesViewModel2; 
DataItem='ManagerIndexesViewModel' (HashCode=22385437); 
target element is 'ContentControl' (Name=''); 
target property is 'Content' (type 'Object')
```

**Pic-1**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Pic-2**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        // AppManager appManager = new AppManager();
        MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.DataContext = mainWindowViewModel;
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Application x:Class="DataDisplayWpfApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataDisplayWpfApp1">
    <Application.Resources>
         
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

=== === === === === === === === === === === === === === === ===

**IndexCalculation**

```cs
public class IndexCalculation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**MainMenuItemMainWindow**

```cs
internal class MainMenuItemMainWindow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }             
    public string Alias { get; set; }
}
```

=== === === === === === === === === === === === === === === ===

**DataContextApp**

```cs
public class DataContextApp
{
    public DataContextApp()
    {
        GenerateDataСalculationIndex();
        
    }

    
    private ObservableCollection<IndexCalculation> calculationIndexes;
    public ObservableCollection<IndexCalculation> СalculationIndexes
    {
        get { return calculationIndexes; }
        set { calculationIndexes = value; }
    }

    
    public void GenerateDataСalculationIndex()
    {
        var calculationIndexes = new ObservableCollection<IndexCalculation>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {
            var indexCalculation = new IndexCalculation()
            {
                Id = i,
                Name = $"NameIndex-{i}",
                Description = $"DescriptionIndex-{i}"
            };
            calculationIndexes.Add(indexCalculation);
        }

        СalculationIndexes = calculationIndexes;
    }
    
}
```

=== === === === === === === === === === === === === === === ===

**MainWindowViewModel**

```cs
internal class MainWindowViewModel : BaseVM
{
    
    public IndexesViewModel indexesViewModel;        
    public ManagerIndexesViewModel managerIndexesViewModel;        
    DataContextApp DataContextApp;
    
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        // this.appManager = appManager;

        DataContextApp = new DataContextApp();

        managerIndexesViewModel = new ManagerIndexesViewModel(DataContextApp);
        indexesViewModel = new IndexesViewModel(DataContextApp);
        
        LoadItemMainMenu();
    }


    #region Title
    private string title = "App `DataDisplayWpfApp1`. Prop title";
    
    public string Title 
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region mainMenuItems        
    private ObservableCollection<MainMenuItemMainWindow> mainMenuItems;

    public ObservableCollection<MainMenuItemMainWindow> MainMenuItems
    {
        get { return mainMenuItems; }
        set
        {
            mainMenuItems = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(MainMenuItemMainWindow));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region SelectedItem
    private MainMenuItemMainWindow selectedMainMenuItem;

    public MainMenuItemMainWindow SelectedMainMenuItem
    {
        get { return selectedMainMenuItem; }
        set 
        {                 
            selectedMainMenuItem = value;                
            
            SwitchView(selectedMainMenuItem.Alias);

            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentView));
        }
    }
    #endregion


    private BaseVM currentView;
    public BaseVM CurrentView
    {
        get { return currentView; }
        set
        {
            currentView = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentView));
        }
    }

    
    private string titleDetail = "TitleDetail";

    public string TitleDetail
    {
        get { return titleDetail; }
        set 
        { 
            titleDetail = value;
            Debug.WriteLine($"titleDetail -- {titleDetail}");
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(TitleDetail));
        }
    }
    

    
    public void LoadItemMainMenu()
    {
        mainMenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MainMenuItemMainWindow>()
        {
            new MainMenuItemMainWindow(){ Name = "Управление коэффициентами", Alias ="ManagerIndexes" },
            new MainMenuItemMainWindow(){ Name = "Коэффициенты", Alias ="Indexes"  },
            new MainMenuItemMainWindow(){ Name = "Поставщки", Alias ="Provider"  }
        };
    }

    public void SwitchView(string nameView)
    {
        switch (nameView)
        {
            case "ManagerIndexes":                    
                CurrentView = managerIndexesViewModel;
                break;

            case "Indexes":                    
                CurrentView = indexesViewModel;
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

=== === === === === === === === === === === === === === === ===
**ManagerIndexesViewModel**

```cs
public class ManagerIndexesViewModel : BaseVM
{
    IndexesViewModel IndexesViewModel2 { get; }
    
    public DataContextApp DataContextApp;


    public ManagerIndexesViewModel(DataContextApp DataContextApp)
    {
        this.DataContextApp = DataContextApp;

        IndexesViewModel2 = new IndexesViewModel(this);

    }

    private IndexCalculation selectedIndexCalculation;

    public IndexCalculation SelectedIndexCalculation
    {
        get { return selectedIndexCalculation; }
        set
        {
            selectedIndexCalculation = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedIndexCalculation));          
        }
    }

}
```

=== === === === === === === === === === === === === === === ===

**IndexesViewModel**

```cs
public class IndexesViewModel : BaseVM
{   
    ManagerIndexesViewModel managerIndexesViewModel;
    
    DataContextApp DataContextApp;

    public IndexesViewModel(ManagerIndexesViewModel managerIndexesViewModel)
    {   

        this.managerIndexesViewModel = managerIndexesViewModel;
        this.DataContextApp = this.managerIndexesViewModel.DataContextApp;

        СalculationIndexs = DataContextApp.СalculationIndexes;            
    }

    public IndexesViewModel(DataContextApp DataContextApp)
    {
        this.DataContextApp = DataContextApp;

        СalculationIndexs = DataContextApp.СalculationIndexes;
    }




    private ObservableCollection<IndexCalculation> calculationIndexs;

    public ObservableCollection<IndexCalculation> СalculationIndexs
    {
        get { return calculationIndexs; }
        set 
        { 
            calculationIndexs = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(СalculationIndexs));
        }
    }

    private IndexCalculation selectedIndexCalculation;

    public IndexCalculation SelectedIndexCalculation
    {
        get { return selectedIndexCalculation; }
        set 
        { 
            selectedIndexCalculation = value;
            
            this.managerIndexesViewModel.SelectedIndexCalculation = selectedIndexCalculation;                

            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedIndexCalculation));
        }
    }

    
    public void LoadDataTest2()
    {
        СalculationIndexs = this.DataContextApp.СalculationIndexes;                       
    }

    
}
```

=== === === === === === === === === === === === === === === ===
**IndexesView**

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="DataDisplayWpfApp1.Views.Views.IndexesView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             
             xmlns:vvm   ="clr-namespace:DataDisplayWpfApp1.ViewModels.Views"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataDisplayWpfApp1.Views.Views"             
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">    
    <DockPanel>
        <UniformGrid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Rows="1" Margin="-3,3">
            <TextBlock FontSize ="30">IndexesView</TextBlock>
            <!--<Button Content="Load"
                            Command="{}"
                            CommandParameter="{}"    
                            Foreground="Blue" Padding="0,5" Margin="3,0"/>

            <Button Content="Create"
                            Command=""
                            CommandParameter=""
                            Foreground="Green" Padding="0,5" Margin="3,0"/>-->
        </UniformGrid>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding СalculationIndexs}"
                    SelectedItem=""                          
                    SelectedIndex="2"
                    x:Name="MainDataGrid"                                                             
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    CanUserAddRows="True"
                    GridLinesVisibility="Vertical"                                  
                    VerticalGridLinesBrush="DarkGray"
                     AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"
                     >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="Auto"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description"  Binding="{Binding Description}" Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

=== === === === === === === === === === === === === === === ===
**ManagerIndexesView**

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="DataDisplayWpfApp1.Views.Views.ManagerIndexesView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"              
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:v ="clr-namespace:DataDisplayWpfApp1.Views.Views"             
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DataDisplayWpfApp1.ViewModels"             
             xmlns:vvm="clr-namespace:DataDisplayWpfApp1.ViewModels.Views"             
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataDisplayWpfApp1.Views.Views" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <!--<UserControl.Resources>        
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vvm:IndexesViewModel}">
            <v:IndexesView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>        
    </UserControl.Resources>-->
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="350" MinWidth="200"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <GroupBox Grid.Column="0" Header="Управление индексами">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Header="Индексы">                        
                        <v:IndexesView DataContext="{Binding IndexesViewModel2}"/>
                        <!--<v:IndexesView />-->
                        <!--<ContentControl Content="{Binding IndexesViewModel2}"/>-->
                    </GroupBox>

                    <!--  GridSplitter -->
                    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="3"/>
                    <!-- **  ========== **  -->
                    
                    <GroupBox Grid.Row="2" Header="ИндексыПоставщкик">
                        <!--<ContentControl Content="{Binding IndexesProvidersView}"/>-->
                        <!--<v:ProvidersAssignedIndexCalculationView DataContext="{Binding ProvidersAssignedIndexViewModel}"/>-->
                    </GroupBox>

                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Grid.Column="1" Header="Поставщики">
                <!--<ContentControl Content="{Binding ProvidersView}"/>-->
                <!--<v:ProvidersNotAssignedIndexCalculationView DataContext="{Binding ProvidersNotAssignedIndexViewModel}"/>-->
            </GroupBox>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="3"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

=== === === === === === === === === === === === === === === ===

**MainWindow**

```xml
<Window x:Class="DataDisplayWpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc ="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:DataDisplayWpfApp1"
        xmlns:vm    ="clr-namespace:DataDisplayWpfApp1.ViewModels"
        xmlns:vvm   ="clr-namespace:DataDisplayWpfApp1.ViewModels.Views"
        xmlns:v     ="clr-namespace:DataDisplayWpfApp1.Views.Views"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:MainWindowViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="{Binding Title}" 
        Height="800" Width="900">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vvm:ManagerIndexesViewModel}">
            <v:ManagerIndexesView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vvm:IndexesViewModel}">
            <v:IndexesView />
        </DataTemplate>
        
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" MinWidth="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!--Группы-->
        <GroupBox Grid.Column="0" Header="Меню">
            <DockPanel>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MainMenuItems}" 
                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMainMenuItem}"                         
                         Name="MainMenu"
                         SelectedIndex="2">
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" 
                        Value="Stretch"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DockPanel>                                
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </DockPanel>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox Header="Панель" Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TitleDetail}" FontSize="26"/>
                    <Separator Background="DarkBlue"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="3"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Совет на будущее: Делайте минимальный, самодостаточный пример, на голом WPF проекте, который опишет конкретную проблему, которую вы хотите решить на простых примитивах. Разбираться в огромной портянке чужого кода мало кто хочет разбираться (думаю вы тоже), поэтому вставайте на место тех, кто не знаком с вами, не знаком с вашими навыками, проектом. и так далее. Представьте, что мы прохожие на улице, вам надо за 5 минут максимально объяснить суть, сможете - помогут, нет - извините... Что касается проблемы - смотрите этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/816149/220553

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Понимаю... Прошу извинить... Но не знаю как сделать куском... Частями всё работает... Собираю в проект: не работает... Так, что вот так... Приношу извинения...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Забыто указание модификатора доступа для свойства в файле `/ViewModels/Views/ManagerIndexesViewModel.cs`.
Из-за этого свойство оказывается приватным и недоступным для WPF, его как будто нет :)

Ваш код:

```
public class ManagerIndexesViewModel : BaseVM
{
    IndexesViewModel IndexesViewModel2 { get; }
```

Надо так:

```
public class ManagerIndexesViewModel : BaseVM
{
    public IndexesViewModel IndexesViewModel2 { get; }
```