# WPF MVVM - Смена UserControl в одном окне

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Есть пара **UserControl**: AuthControl и CalculateControl.
Для этих контролов есть ViewModel: AuthViewModel.cs, CalculateViewModel.cs, также имеется RootVM, в котором устанавливается нужная VM свойству CurrentContentVM.
**RootVM:**

```
public RootViewModel(ViewModelBase view)
{
    CurrentContentVM = view;
}

private ViewModelBase currentContentVM;
public ViewModelBase CurrentContentVM
{
    get
    {
        return currentContentVM;
    }
    set
    {
        currentContentVM = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => CurrentContentVM);
    }
}
```

Необходимо реализовать переход с контрола AuthControl в контрол CalculateControl. Я это сделал так:
**код MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AuthViewModel}">
        <local:AuthControl />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CalculateViewModel}">
        <view:CalculateControl />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CaloriesViewModel}">
        <view:CaloriesControl/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentContentVM}"/>
</Grid>
```

код **AuthViewModel**

```
private string _fieldFio;
RootViewModel root;
public string FieldFio
{
    get
    {
        return _fieldFio;
    }
    set
    {
        _fieldFio = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => FieldFio);
    }
}

public ICommand CommandLogin //Это команда на кнопке
{
    get
    {
        return _commandLogin ?? (_commandLogin = new RelayCommand(() => {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FieldFio) && FieldFio.Equals("Admin"))                    
                root = new RootViewModel(new CaloriesViewModel());                    
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Неверный формат входной строки");
        }));
    }
}
```

DataContext я устанавливаю прямо в коде:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();            
    DataContext = new ViewModels.RootViewModel(new ViewModels.AuthViewModel());
}
```

В общем беда в том, что при нажатии на кнопку контрол не меняется. Что можете подсказать? (Использую MVVM Light)

Comment: `root = new RootViewModel(new CaloriesViewModel())` - вот ваша ошибка. Вы ломаете привязку, так как `new RootViewModel != DataContext`. Другими словами сделав `var obj1 = new RootViewModel(); var obj2 = new RootViewModel();` вы получите совершенно два разных объекта, не один, а два. Вам надо передавать ссылку на RootViewModel в нужную VM (например через конструктор) и уже с этой ссылкой работать.

Answer (score 0):

**DataContext** устанавливается один раз при инициализации главной формы и больше никогда не изменяется. Изменяется только **CurrentContentVM** в xaml. Поэтому насчет нарушения я бы с вами поспорил.

Разобрался. Вот решение, может кому пригодится:
В MainWindow.xaml устанавливаем **DataContext** на **RootViewModel**:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AuthViewModel}">
            <local:AuthControl />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CalculateViewModel}">
            <view:CalculateControl />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CaloriesViewModel}">
            <view:CaloriesControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:RootViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentContentVM}"/>
    </Grid>
```

В RootViewModel объявляем статическое поле root. В конструкторе указываем начальную форму и далее root присваиваем текущую ссылку.

```
public static RootViewModel root;
        public RootViewModel()
        {
            CurrentContentVM = new AuthViewModel();
            root = this;
        }
```

В AuthViewModel для смены контрола просто пишем:

```
RootViewModel.root.CurrentContentVM = new CalculateViewModel();
```

Comment: [Оставлю тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553). Ну и `static` - не есть хорошо. Почему вы просто не передадите нужную VM в другую VM, без статика? Просто пишете что то вроде `private MainVM MainVM {get;} public CustomVM(MainVM mainVM){ MainVM = mainVM; }` и все, дальше делайте что угодно с главной VM. По поводу `DataContext` - есть проекты, где она меняется, но в целом да, задается при инициализации. А про нарушение - почитайте принципы MVVM, как слои должны знать друг о друге и вы увидите, что V не должен быть связан с VM/M и написание в V слое`DataContext = МояVM` - нарушение.

Comment: Другими словами, попробуйте удалить из проекта все классы, все VM/M слои и оставьте чисто дизайн, чистый XAML и все, что к нему относится. Запустится ли приложение? А если делать по **строгому** MVVM, то должно (естественно без данных, чисто дизайн). Но как не крути, вас не заставляют следовать строго MVVM, это всего лишь рекомендации, которые вы сами решаете, нужны они вам или нет.

Comment: Почитайте ещё про Composition Root (место "сборки" приложения), что это такое.

Answer (score -1):

```
DataContext =  ViewModels.RootViewModel(ViewModels.AuthViewModel());
```

Comment: Это является нарушением правил MVVM, ибо DataContext - это контрол, а точней View слой, который должен быть отделен от других слоев и быть совершенно независимым. Делается это при помощи конечно привязок. Так что DataContext должен по хорошему задаться один раз и быть неизменным.